# Angular2 directive, constructor vs onInit

Tags: angular

I am simply trying to figure out what the difference between the constructor and the onInit function is in a Directive in Angular2. To me both seems to be used when the object is created, so why would you not only use the constructor?

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35763811/5043867

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one (constructor) is related to the class instantiation and has nothing to do with Angular2. I mean a constructor can be used on any class. You can put in it some initialization processing for the newly created instance.

The second one corresponds to a lifecycle hook of Angular2 components:

- `ngOnChanges` is called when an input or output binding value changes
- `ngOnInit` is called after the first `ngOnChanges`

So you should use `ngOnInit` if initialization processing relies on bindings of the component (for example component parameters defined with `@Input`), otherwise the constructor would be enough...

Comment: So is there a reason to not always use onInit?

Comment: For example if you want to use injected objects without setting them as class properties...

Comment: Injection is done at the constructor level. But using ngOnInit for other initializations is fine ;-)