# Pass data between classes with @Input Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am a noob here, but I need some of help, I am doing a Ionic 2 aplication and this is about search, so i have a main template which i will insert a new template with result's, so i got problem fot to pass the search key from de main template to the result template, i was trying with the @Input but I am a noob, and I want learn,I would greatly appreciate your help...

This is the main code App.html my variable is "prueba":

```
<div id="sbar">
 <ion-searchbar id="searchbox" (keyup)='upkey($event)' (keydown)='downkey($event)' [recibir]="prueba" //here i declare the bindding variables></ion-searchbar>
</div>
```

this is my App.js code where i assign the search key:

```
class MyApp {
  constructor(app: IonicApp, platform: Platform, http: Http) {
   this.app = app;
   this.platform = platform;
   this.http=http;

   this.prueba = "Search_Key"; //my variable

   this.Leyes = [];
   this.url = 'http://##########/resultados.json?q='; 
   this.initializeApp();

   this.pages = [
     { imagen: 'build/img/home.png', title: 'Home', component: GettingStartedPage },
     { imagen: 'build/img/info38.png', title: 'Ayuda', component: AyudaHTML },
     { imagen: 'build/img/faq7.png', title: 'Preguntas Frecuentes', component: FaqHTML }
     { imagen: 'build/img/cloud158.png', title: 'Actualizaciones', component: ActualizacionesHTML },
     { imagen: 'build/img/news29.png', title: 'Novedades', component: NovedadesHTML },
     { imagen: 'build/img/two205.png', title: '¿Te gustaría colaborar?', component: ColaborarHTML },
     { imagen: 'build/img/multiple25.png', title: 'Acerca', component: AcercaHTML},
     ];
  this.rootPage = GettingStartedPage;
  }

  initializeApp() {
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  });
}
```

And this is the other template where I receive  the Input with the name "recibir":

```
export class GettingStartedPage{
    @Input() recibir;//this the Search_key that I receive
    constructor(app: IonicApp,http: Http) {
        this.http=http;
        this.Leyes = [];
        this.url = 'http://www.##########/resultados.json?q='; 
        alert("Recibira :" + this.recibir);
        this.buscar(this.recibir);
    }
 }
```

Please help me...it doesn't work i don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use that:

```
export class GettingStartedPage implements OnInit{

constructor(app: IonicApp,http: Http) {

this.http=http;
this.Leyes = [];
this.url = 'http://www.leybook.com/resultados.json?q='; to  
this.val = app.getComponent('searchbox').value;(<--- This gets the value directly of "searchbox" in my main template, This worked for me)
alert(this.val);
}
ngOnInit(){    
  this.buscar(this.val); 
}
}
```

i hope to help to other noob like me .... (Y)

Answer (score 2):

The value for an input is not yet available in the constructor.

Use `ngOnInit()` instead. When `ngOnInit()` is called, Angular is done initializing the component and bindings are resovled.

```
export class GettingStartedPage{
    @Input() recibir;//this the Search_key that I receive
    constructor(app: IonicApp,http: Http) {
        this.http=http;
        this.Leyes = [];
        this.url = 'http://www.##########/resultados.json?q='; 
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        alert("Recibira :" + this.recibir);
        this.buscar(this.recibir);
    }
 }
```

See also

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/OnInit-interface.html
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html
- [Difference between Constructor and ngOnInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit-in-angular-2)

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not very helpful. Any error message?

Comment: I did that you said but nothing and it doesn't show any error message... only it doesn't show the information