# Angular 2 Component Constructor Vs OnInit

Tags: angular, constructor, ngoninit

If I want function x to happen every time a component loads, whether its the first time, I navigate to a different site and navigate back or it's the fifth time the component has loaded.

What should I put function x in? The component constructor or OnInit?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Constructor is predefined default method of the typescript class. There is no relation between Angular and `constructor`. Normally we use `constructor` to define/initialize some variables, but when we have tasks related to Angular's bindings we move to Angular's `ngOnInit` life cycle hook. `ngOnInit` is called just after the constructor call. We can also do the same work in the constructor but its preferable to use `ngOnInit` to start Angular's binding.

in order to use `ngOnInit` we have to import this hook from the core library:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core'
```

Then we implement this interface with exported class (this is not compulsory to implement this interface but generally we did).

Example of using both:

```
export class App implements OnInit{
  constructor(){
     //called first time before the ngOnInit()
  }

  ngOnInit(){
     //called after the constructor and called  after the first ngOnChanges() 
  }
}
```

For more detail see also  [Difference between Constructor and ngOnInit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35763811/5043867)

Comment: But you didn't answer the actual question. which one we should use in this case..?

Comment: ngOnInit is not called just after the constructor call, between of them there is ngOnChanges: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: @JugalSingh You should use ngOnInit for binding related work. Constructor usage is not recommended as it affects the performance. Unless there is a dire need of initializing something prior hand, onInit serves the purposes very well

Comment: Kind of feels like web forms hell all over again. I just wanted to know that the constructor was called before ngInit in the <strike>webforms</strike> life-cycle

Answer (score 31):

The first one (constructor) is related to the class instantiation and has nothing to do with Angular2. I mean a constructor can be used on any class. You can put in it some initialization processing for the newly created instance.

The second one corresponds to a lifecycle hook of Angular2 components:

- `ngOnChanges` is called when an input or output binding value changes
- `ngOnInit` is called after the first `ngOnChanges`

So you should use `ngOnInit` if initialization processing of your function relies on bindings of the component (for example component parameters defined with `@Input`), otherwise the constructor would be enough...

Comment: Are there any situations where using  `ngOnInit` over the constructor would be bad?

Answer (score 31):

`constructor()` is a typescript feature and is called for `new SomeClass()`. The constructor ensures proper field initialization order in class hierarchies.

`ngOnInit` is an Angular2 lifecycle method that is called by Angular when it's done building the component and after it evaluated the bindings and updated the inputs the first time.

See also [Difference between Constructor and ngOnInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit-in-angular-2/35764845#35764845)

Comment: You are 100% right and I upvote for you. In my mind, if we describe `ngOnInit` as React's `componentDidMount`, all the confusion will be gone. But to be honest, for developers, we just need to have only one initialization phrase, no matter it is called. The very old fashion way is use a function like class to build up a component class, so the injection is passed as arguments in and you only need one `$onInit`. Ng2+ is not a piece of beautiful artwork.

Comment: The constructor is a TypeScript language feature with certain restrictions. There is nothing Angular can do aboit it.