# When to create constructor in Angular2 typescript?

Tags: typescript, angular

Here are some example constructors from the [Angular 2 docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/):

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'Tour of heroes';
    heroes: Hero[];
    selectedHero: Hero;

    constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

    getHeroes() {
        this.HeroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
    }
}
```

and...

```
class Car {
    constructor(engine, tires, doors){
        this.engine = engine;
        this.tires = tires;
        this.doors = doors;
    }
}
```

I don't understand Why and When to create a `constructor()` in angular 2 /typescript (I've read the official documentation where they create a constructor for Dependency Injection and for Services).

Comment: +1. I struggle to know what should be in a constructor (apart from "as little as possible") and what shouldn't.  I guess it's a wider programming concept but my reading hasn't yielded anything particularly clear which describes constructors and their purpose in a simple way.

Comment: Hi Sarvesh, It could be better for others if you inserted your code as text.

Comment: @J.Chomel I think now Its better :)

Comment: I've edited the post to make it a little clearer and to use code rather than images for examples.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Constructors define which parameters to provide when instantiate your objects. In TypeScript, you can also add modifiers like `private` or `public` to define in the same time class properties and set their values with the provided ones.

For example:

```
class Car {
  constructor(private engine:string, private tires:string, private doors:number){
  }
}
```

is similar to:

```
class Car {
  constructor(engine:string, tires:string, doors:number){
    this.engine = engine;
    this.tires = tires;
    this.doors = doors;
  }
}
```

In Angular2 constructors are used for dependency injection. The associated decorator (`@Component` or `Injectable`) collects metadata (types or hints within `@Inject`) to determine what to provide to the object to instantiate.

Be aware that constructors aren't part of the component lifecycle. Properties can be set later by Angular2 at this level...

Comment: See [this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Rectangle%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(private%20height%3Anumber%2C%20private%20width%3Anumber)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D) on the TypeScript playground for an example you can play around with.

Answer (score 5):

Controller constructors are mainly used for dependency injection / services as you mentioned and also (in my apps) for initializing complex default values based off the services themselves. Since the constructor runs before the controllers template is initialized - no variables will be rendered accurately, hence the need for `ngOnInit` and other similar methods. These 'bootstrap' methods should be used to perform the normal 'constructing' duties so the template/view can access the data.

Regarding service constructors, a few of mine use the constructor normally and initialize various parts of the service based off existing user data as they act a lot more like standard classes.

These answers will be of help:

- [Difference between Constructor and ngOnInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit)
- [Angular 2 Component Constructor Vs OnInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35845554/angular-2-component-constructor-vs-oninit)