# Ionic 3 app is not redirecting to pages when I redirected it from storage.get('session') function

Tags: android, angular, redirect, ionic3

I have redirected my app from `app.component.ts` by setting `rootpage` as follow

```
rootPage:any=HomePage;
```

Later when I implemented login functionality I decided to redirect page as follow

```js
rootPage:any;//=HomePage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, 
    statusBar: StatusBar, 
    splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private storage: Storage,
    private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {

      platform.ready().then(() => {
        // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
        // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
        statusBar.styleDefault();
        splashScreen.hide();

        // Check session and redirect
        storage.get('session').then((val) => {
          if(val){
            this.rootPage=HomePage;
          }else{
            this.rootPage=LoginPage;
          }
        });
      });
  }
```

But my page is not redirecting .

**What I tried -**

**1.** Page is redirecting when I am using `this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` after setting rootpage, but my map in homepage is not loading when I am redirecting this way.

Is there any better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably is that you assign the page to `rootPage` inside a promise. Because it is an async operation, the component renders before it is a assigned a root page. To fix it, you can simply use `navCtrl.setRoot` instead and wait to hide the splashscreen.

```
ngOnInit() {
  platform.ready().then(() => {
    // Check session and redirect
    storage.get('session').then((val) => {
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();

      if (val) {
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
      } else {
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Since you're not initializing root page anymore, I would also recommend doing this in `ngOnInit` instead of the constructor. It wasn't the cause of your problem, but it is [recommended to do so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35845554/angular-2-component-constructor-vs-oninit/35846307#35846307).

Comment: When I try to do this I got following error - Error: No provider for NavController!

Comment: This is fixed when I redirected user from ngOnInit()

Comment: The error is because you didn't initialize `NavController` in your constructor. Glad you figured it out though

Answer (score 0):

Everything worked fine when I redirected user from ngOnInit() as follow

```
ngOnInit() {
 // Check session and redirect
 this.storage.get('session').then((val) => {

   if(val){
     this.rootPage=HomePage;
   }else{
     this.rootPage=LoginPage;
   }

 });
}
```