# Binding the values from response and make the checkboxes with those value using angular2

Tags: angular

I have 2 API, 1 API is used to hit for getting menu list. Another **API** is used for fetching the data with Values after saving the checked list. So based on data i must uncheck the boxes with value as 0 and check if value is 1.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-upcmhm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

TS:

```
getUserMenu() {
let data = [{HasCaseManagement: 1,HasDicom: 0,HasEMR: 1,HasHomeDashboard: 1,HasReport: 1,HasSystemSettings: 1,HasUserManagement: 0,Id: 54,UserId: 1387}]
        data.map(a => {
          this.userMenu.map(r => {
            if (r == a) {
              r.isChecked = true;
              this.selectedMenuIds.push(a)
              this.selectedMenuIds = this.userMenu.filter(x => x.isChecked).map(y => y);
            }
          })
        })
   }
```

Here the data is the response which I got from API, for that particular user. So that I can bind the check value if it is 1, uncheck if it is 0.

How to bind the values from the response and make the checkboxes with those value as using angular2?

Comment: Can you elaborate more? I don't see any problem in your demo.

Comment: in my demo, it is binding according to UserMenu, but i want that to get check and uncheck values based on the response got in getUserMenu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like in [Stackblitz Fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6qrjfi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

If that is the case, then you're missing:

```
 getUserMenu() {
    ...
    this.userMenu = data;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUserMenu();
  }
```

You can read the explanation of `ngOnInit()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35845554/angular-2-component-constructor-vs-oninit/35846307#35846307) and [here](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit)

Summary:

> A lifecycle hook that is called after Angular has initialized all
>   data-bound properties of a directive. Define an ngOnInit() method to
>   handle any additional initialization tasks.

More explanation about [lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)