# How does consumer supply component constructor parameters in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular

I want to modify the field of a component instance. 
For example, in test.component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'test',
})
export class TestComponent {    
    @Input() temp;
    temp2;
    constructor(arg) {
        this.temp = arg;
        this.temp2 = arg * 2;
    }
}
```

I want to set the values of temp and temp2 using the constructor. I know one approach is to use input property by doing something like:

```
<test [temp]='1'></test>
```

However, this is done after the constructing time and temp2 won't change accordingly. How can I supply component constructor argument from a consumer's point of view, such that the value of "temp" and "temp2" are set at constructing time?

Thanks!

Comment: but what is `arg`? can you provide plunk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact inputs of a component are only available from the ngOnInit method because of the component lifecycle:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'test',
})
export class TestComponent {    
    @Input() temp;

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.temp);
    }
}
```

Moreover we can only use parameters in the component constructor that are provided through dependency injection.

So you can't use the constructor for the temp property because the component lifecycle. Regarding it depends on how you make it available. If it's through dependency injection, it will work but you need to use the @Inject decorator to specify what to inject.

You could also have a look at this question for more details:

- [Difference between Constructor and ngOnInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit?s=0|3.5285)

Answer (score 0):

**sharedServcie.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class sharedService{
  test:string="Angular2";
}
```

**boot.ts**

```
import {sharedService} from './sharedService';
...
...
bootstrap[App,[sharedService]]
```

---

```
import {sharedService} from './sharedService';
@Component({
    selector: 'test',
})
export class TestComponent {    
    temp;
    constructor(sharedService:sharedService) {
        this.temp = sharedService.test;
        console.log(this.temp) //Angular2
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your quick reply! Service is a good idea, but is it possible to supply the argument in the html, for example, <test [temp]='Angular2'></test> or <test>Angular2</test>, such that a consumer can supply the argument easily?

Comment: AFAIK `<test [temp]='Angular2'></test>` `temp` can be used freely in `test` cmp...You dont need to inject it. I dont understand your context fully...

Comment: In the case where there is another instance var temp2 of test cmp associated with temp (for example, temp2 = temp * 2; ), using @Input() to change temp wont't change the value of temp2. Therefore, I want to supply argument during constructing.

Comment: of course It will change temp2 if you change temp !

Comment: In case you don't fully understand my context, I updated the question, hope this can be more clear. By using input property, I can only change temp, but temp2 will not update accordingly. (I've tried)

Answer (score 0):

I think the [answer Thierry Templier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36097661/how-does-consumer-supply-component-constructor-parameters-in-angular-2#36098738) explains your problem, but

you say in a comment:

> I updated the question, hope this can be more clear. By using input
>   property, I can only change temp, but temp2 will not update
>   accordingly.

I hope this is what you want to achieve and help you.

```js
    import {Input, Component} from 'angular2/core'

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-test',
      template: `
      <h1> arg value:    {{ arg }} </h1>
      <h1> temp value:   {{ temp }} </h1>
      <h1> temp1 value:  {{ temp1 }} </h1>
    `
    })

    export class test {
      @Input() arg  : number;
      temp : number;
      temp1: number;

      constructor(){

      }

      ngOnInit(){
        this.temp  = this.arg;
        this.temp1 = this.arg * 2;
      }

    }

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      directives: [test],
      template: `
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <my-test [arg]="1"></my-test>
    `
    })
    export class App {
      constructor() {
       this.name = 'Angular2';
      } 
    }
```

test <kbd>[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yOXMUsoAWTLtJTIdnX4a?p=preview)</kbd>