# Authentication flow in Angular 2

Tags: angular

How would you implement the following flow in Angular 2?

I suppose this is a fairly standard scenario in an application requiring authentication.

The config data required by the application is defined in an injectable service.

- When the application starts (bootstraps), check localStorage.
- If localstorage contains valid JWT token, make http call to retrieve config data. When response is received and stored in the service, route to Home.
- If localstorage does not contain valid JWT token, route to login. When user submits login, http call, put received JWT in localstorage, make another http call (same as above) and when response is received and stored in the service, route to Home.
- Later, the protected components have a routerOnActivate that verifies
  that the config data is present in the service (meaning the user is
  logged in). If not, route to login.

Do you think of a better approach?

Where exactly should I implement the logic that checks the localstorage and asynchronously fetches the config via http call?

In the constructor of the App component that is bootstrapped?

How to prevent further execution of the other components (they rely on the presence of this config data)?

Comment: Here's [an example](https://medium.com/@blacksonic86/authentication-in-angular-2-958052c64492#.a714r26b4)

Comment: Thanks Sasxa, I'll check this example. At first sight it seems to match the architecture I want to achieve.

Comment: @sasxa Good article but it still uses the deprecated router.  It would be nice to see example using the new router.

Comment: Sounds good! Doing almost same here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in my opinion it sounds like a good approach!

> Where exactly should I implement the logic that checks the localstorage and asynchronously fetches the config via http call? In the constructor of the App component that is bootstrapped?

First, **do not use the `constructor`** of the App component.

You should use constructor() to setup Dependency Injection and not much else. Mostly we use `ngOnInit` for all the initialization/deceleration and avoid stuff to work in the constructor. The constructor should only be used to initialize class members but shouldn't do actual "work". More info [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit).

Second, let's see where exactly to implement the logic. Create an `AuthenticationService`.

1. Implement `login()` method and add `isUserLoggedIn` boolean on the `AuthenticationService`. When user logs-in, store the `JWT` token inside the LocalStorage. Additionally, switch the `isUserLoggedIn` to `true`.
2. Implement `isUserLogged()` method on the `AuthenticationService`. Call this method always when the application starts, for example inside the App's `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook. The `isUserLogged()` method logic should be the following:

   - First, check if there is a login token in the LocalStorage. If no -> user is not logged in. Switch the `isUserLoggedIn` to `false`.
   - Second, if there is a login token in the LocalStorage - you must check if it is still valid (or it has expired). Your API should provide you a method for that, something like `/check-if-user-is-logged`. Call it and based on the result - switch the `isUserLoggedIn`.
3. Implement `logout()` method on the `AuthenticationService`. When user logs-in, wipe-out the `JWT` token from the LocalStorage. Additionally, switch the `isUserLoggedIn` to `false`.

Then, implement an auth guard on all of the protected routes.

> How to prevent further execution of the other components (they rely on the presence of this config data)?

Use the `isUserLoggedIn` boolean on the `AuthenticationService`. Additionally, you can apply other methods on the `AuthenticationService` that check for a specific config present.

Plus, use the auth guard on all of the protected routes.