# What is the practical difference between using ngOnInit and constructor in Angular 2 Component definition?

Tags: javascript, angular

I know ngOnInit is Angular specific syntax while constructor is Typescript/ES2015 class syntax. But when it come to their usage and execution in Angular 2 Components what are the differences?

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/what-is-the-difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

The constructor is called when the class instance is created by Angulars DI.

`ngOnInit()` is a lifecycle hook that is called later by Angular2 change detection. 
When `@Input()`s are updated by change detection, `ngOnChanges(changes)` is called. 
After `ngOnChanges(changes)` was called the first time `ngOnInit()` is called.

The main difference is therefore, that change detection has been run and that `@Input()`s are initialized.