# Why it is important to import OnInit

Tags: angular

Without importing OnInit and implements

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.recipies=this.recipeService.getRecipies();
}
```

This is still working fine without  any complain so why should i use 
like :

```
import { Component,EventEmitter,Output , OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class RecipiesListComponent implements OnInit{}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Interface are optional as per the [angular documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#interface-optional) so you can use it without `importing` and `implementing` it.

Angular instead inspects directive and component classes and calls the hook methods if they are defined but it's good practice to add interfaces to TypeScript directive classes in order to benefit from strong typing and editor tooling.

Answer (score 1):

We have to import OnInit in order to use like this (actually implementing OnInit is not mandatory but considered good practice).

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
```

Check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit). Hope you got your answer.