# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPosts' of undefined

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get post data using http service in angular 2. and dont understand what wrong I'm doing here..
I'm using Plunker here
I've console.logged and it is showing this error. How to solve this this undefined?

Error:

```
ZoneAwareError
message
:"(SystemJS) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPosts' of undefined↵ 
at execute     
(https://run.plnkr.co/YV2OxH7SpFuwfVbA/src/app.ts!transpiled:48:30)↵        
at ZoneDelegate.invoke  
(https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.7.5/dist/zone.js:242:26)↵      at 
Zone.run (https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.7.5/dist/zone.js:113:43)↵     at 
https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.7.5/dist/zone.js:535:57↵        at 
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask 
(https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.7.5/dist/zone.js:275:35)↵      at 
 Zone.runTask (https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.7.5/dist/zone.js:151:47)↵        
at drainMicroTaskQueue 
(https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.7.5/dist/zone.js:433:35)↵  Error loading  
 https://run.plnkr.co/YV2OxH7SpFuwfVbA/src/main.ts"
 name
 :
 "Error"
```

app.ts

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {PostsService} from './posts';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h3>Posts</h3>
    <div *ngFor="let post of posts | async">
        <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
        <p>{{post.body}}</p>
    </div>
  `,
  providers: [PostsService]

})
export class App {
  posts:Post[];
  constructor(private postsService: PostsService) {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

  this.postsService.getPosts().subscribe(posts => {
  this.posts = posts;
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, HttpModule ],
  declarations: [ App  ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}

interface Post{
    id: number;
    title: string;
    body: string;
}
```

posts.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class PostsService {
    constructor(private http: Http){
        console.log('PostsService Initialized...');
    }

    getPosts(){
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

Here is plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/jWaPbNlqsqXoOFFRzhhX?p=preview

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/Bacad9XM4pHT0KUVYyfH?p=preview

Comment: you are not calling service method inside constructor . best place is to caal service methods on ngOnInt method

Comment: Thank you @yurzui  that plunker is working :)

Comment: Thank you @YashveerSingh for information

Comment: can you please mark and accept my answer please . i answered before all others

Comment: @YashveerSingh upvoted :)

Comment: but you didnt upvoted my answer i think . please have a look

Comment: @Sushant i checked but I think my answer was not accepted / up voted please accept or up vote . it will help me to build some points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sushant,

You need to subscribe in the body of a method -- the current location you are placing the code will be expected as a declaration and will be acted upon before the service is instantiated.

You have several options, here is one:

```
import {OnInit} from '@angular/core'
...
export class App implements OnInit {
  posts:Post[];
  constructor(private postsService: PostsService) {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.postsService.getPosts().subscribe(posts => {
      this.posts = posts;
    }
}
```

OnInit is called as a lifecycle hook when the component is instantiated, so you will be able to refer to the 'live' observable here.

Consider this link to the Angular 2 docs regarding lifecycle hooks:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html

Comment: Added ngOnInit and code is working now .. Thank you for the information :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
constructor(private postsService: PostsService) {
  this.postsService.getPosts().subscribe(posts => {
    console.log(posts);
    this.posts = posts;
  }
}
```

Comment: [It is preferable to do this in `ngOnInit()` rather than in the `constructor()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit)

Comment: thanks this is what i mentioned in my comments before posting answer .