# Angular 2 assign css style at runtime

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am attempting to create a circular arrangement of links using Angular 2. I have a function that sets the fixed location of the `style.left` and `style.top` for each link, based on the number of links in the circle. I've attempted to use this code in the constructor of my component, but Angular fails to build, giving me an error that the `items.length` property is null.

Here's my component class code which is a mix of typescript and javascript:

```
export class PlayersComponent {
items: any;
constructor() {
  this.items = document.querySelector('.circle');
  for(var i = 0, l = this.items.length; i < l; i++){
    this.items[i].style.left = (50 - 35*Math.cos(-0.5 * Math.PI - 2*(1/l)*i*Math.PI)).toFixed(4) + "%";
    this.items[i].style.top = (50 + 35*Math.sin(-0.5 * Math.PI - 2*(1/l)*i*Math.PI)).toFixed(4) + "%";
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a side note, the constructor is used for dependency injection not for doing the 'work' you should be doing this within ngOnInit(); see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit

Comment: It is also a mix of angular and not angular. Please read the guides how to program with angular

Comment: You should style binding instead `[style.left.px]="styleValues[index]"` or `ngStyle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of accessing element inside constructor.You have to implement **AfterViewInit** and access element inside **ngAfterViewInit** method.

DOM is initialize after viewInit.Please check [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/AfterViewInit-class.html)

Refer the following code:

```
import {Component,AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core'; 
export class PlayersComponent implements AfterViewInit{
  items: any;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.items = document.querySelector('.circle');
     for(var i = 0, l = this.items.length; i < l; i++){
        this.items[i].style.left = (50 - 35*Math.cos(-0.5 * Math.PI - 2(1/l)*i*Math.PI)).toFixed(4) + "%";
        this.items[i].style.top = (50 + 35*Math.sin(-0.5 * Math.PI - 2*(1/l)*i*Math.PI)).toFixed(4) + "%";
  }
}
```

Please mark it as answer if it helps!!!