# Angular2 - not displaying data from component

Tags: angular

I am following a course on Angular2 beta versiopn, where I have 2 components whose data I am trying to display. This is my app.component:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {CoursesComponent} from './courses.component'
import {AuthorsComponent} from './authors.component'

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <h1>Hello Angular 2 App</h1>
        <courses></courses>
        <authors></authors>
        `,
    directives: [CoursesComponent, AuthorsComponent]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

And this is the courses component:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {CourseService} from './course.service';
import {AutoGrowDirective} from './auto-grow.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'courses',
  template: `
    <h2>{‌{ title }}</h2>
    <input type="text" autoGrow />
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="#course of courses">
      {‌{ course }}
      </li>
    </ul>
    `,
  providers: [CourseService],
  directives: [AutoGrowDirective]
})
export class CoursesComponent {
  title: string = "The title of courses page";
  courses;

  constructor(courseService: CourseService) {
    this.courses = courseService.getCourses();
  }
}
```

And this is the author component:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'
import {AuthorService} from './author.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'authors',
  template: `
    <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="#author of authors">
      {{ author }}
      </li>
    </ul>
    `,
  providers: [AuthorService]
})

export class AuthorsComponent {
  title: string = "The title of authors page";
  authors;

  constructor(authorService: AuthorService) {
    this.authors = authorService.getAuthors();
  }
}
```

The interpolated data from authors component is displaying but not from courses component.
I don't know why, and how can I debug it?

**Update**

I managed to show the data with this code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'courses',
  template: `
    <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
    <input type="text" autoGrow />
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="#course of courses">
      {{ course }}
      </li>
    </ul>
    `,
  providers: [CourseService],
  directives: [AutoGrowDirective]
})

export class CoursesComponent {
  title: string = "The title of courses page";
  courses;

  constructor(courseService: CourseService) {
    this.courses = courseService.getCourses();
  }
}
```

If someone can explain me what is the difference in this code and the first one in the question, I would be very grateful, because I can't see any difference other than an empty row between component decorator and the class declaration? Even when I just copy paste the code from here and make that space I still can't get it to show the data, but when I use the code that I showed here now, then it works! How, why? I how can I debug the app, when get myself in this situations? And, there were no errors in the console, when the data wasn't showing up.

Comment: Not an answer, but I would perhaps reconsider if you are just starting to learn Angular, that you would upgrade to final version. I mean, Angular 4 beta is already out ;) If you are looking for tutorials, I think that the TOH tutorial covers everything pretty good https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/ But if you want to stick to beta, that's fine too :)

Comment: are you getting Template parse errors in your developer console ?

Answer (score 1):

I would check out this article:

[Difference between Constructor and ngOnInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit)

It is generally better practice to initialize your service in the constructor and use the angular "ngOnInit" to call your service. The article explains thoroughly why.