# Angular2: Updating and sharing data between components

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to make something that looks like this:
[image]

Looking for a way to make Service feed the latest data to subscribed components whenever its necessary. For example: Component3 writes changes to the API > Component1 and Component2 have to get the latest data.

Currently both components are subscribed to an observable returned by the service and this causes 2 API requests if both are rendered. This feels wrong. In my understanding these components should be fed the data and not request it on their own. To be clear: the data returned by this service is always being used in Component1 while Component2 is rendered optionally.

Here's some snippets and a bit of description of what I've done so far:

**Service** gets data through HTTP from API. **Component1** and **Component2** are subscribed to observable returned by **Service**:

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http } from "@angular/http";

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()

export class GroupService{
    constructor(private _http: Http){}

    getGroups(){
        return this._http.get('/assets/groups.json')
            .map((res) => {
                return res.json();
            });
    }
}
```

**Component1** and **Component2** are basically the same in terms of functionality. Here's one of them:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { router } from '../../app.router';
import { GroupService } from '../../services/group.service';
import { Group } from '../../interfaces/group.interface';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-sidebar',
    templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.scss'],
})

export class SidebarComponent
{
    router;
    groups: Group[];

    constructor(private _groupService: GroupService){
        this.router = router;
        this.getGroups();
    }

    getGroups(){
        this._groupService.getGroups()
            .subscribe((groups) => {
                this.groups = groups;
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A slightly different approach from seidme's, that I would personally prefer:

Set up a data stream in `GroupService` and use that in your components.

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class GroupService {
    private groupSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
    public group$: Observable = this.groupSource.asObservable();

    constructor(private _http: Http) {}

    getGroups() {
        this._http.get('/assets/groups.json')
            .map((res) => {
                return res.json();
            })
            .subscribe((groups) => this.groupSource.next(groups));
    }
}
```

Then in your components, just do this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { router } from '../../app.router';
import { GroupService } from '../../services/group.service';
import { Group } from '../../interfaces/group.interface';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-sidebar',
    templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.scss'],
})

export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
    router;
    groups: Observable;

    constructor(private _groupService: GroupService){
        this.router = router;
    }

    ngOnInit {
        this.groups = this._groupService.group$;
    }
}
```

Then in your template, use the `async` pipe: `{{ groups | async }}`. It will take care of subscribing to (and disposing of) the observable for you.

Now whenever you call `GroupService.getGroups()` from any component, all the other ones will update automatically.

Also, using `OnInit` is slightly preferable to doing stuff in the constructor, see [Difference between Constructor and ngOnInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using [BehaviorSubject as a delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular2)  is probably the most convenient option for your use case. Register the `BehaviorSubject` in the service and subscribe to it in all components that need to be updated when any of those components requests new data.

This is how the service should look like:

```
@Injectable()
export class GroupService {

    groupsSource: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

    constructor(private _http: Http) { }

    getGroups(): void {
        this._http.get('/assets/groups.json')
            .map((res) => res.json())
            .subscribe((groups) => this.groupsSource.next(groups)); // Update all components subscribed to the BehaviorSubjet
    }
}
```

Component 1, requests new data:

```
export class Component1 implements OnInit {

    groups: any;

    constructor(private _groupService: GroupService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._groupService.groupsSource.subscribe((groups) => {
            this.groups = groups;
        });

        this._groupService.getGroups();
    }
}
```

Component 2, gets updated automatically:

```
export class Component2 implements OnInit {

    groups: any;

    constructor(private _groupService: GroupService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._groupService.groupsSource.subscribe((groups) => {
            this.groups = groups;
        });
    }
}
```

With the `BehaviorSubject` you can get the most recent value it holds without even subscribing to it:

```
export class Component3 implements OnInit{

    groups: any;

    constructor(private _groupService: GroupService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.groups = this._groupService.groupsSource.getValue();
    }
}
```