# angular2-tree-component is not expanded by default

Tags: javascript, html, angular, treeview

I am using [angular2-tree-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-tree-component) and want to show already expanded tree.
Now my tree **is not expanded** after loading page:

[image]

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="sidebartree-ul" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': 'white'}">
    <tree-root class="panel-body " [nodes]="Items" [options]="customTemplateStringOptions" 
        #tree >
        <ng-template #loadingTemplate>
            Loading..
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template #treeNodeTemplate let-node>
            <tree-node-expander [node]="node"></tree-node-expander>
            <span *ngIf="node?.data?.expanded === true " title="{{node.data.subTitle}}">
                <b> {{ node.data.name }} {{ childrenCount(node) }} </b></span>            
            <span *ngIf="!node?.data?.expanded === true" title="{{node.data.subTitle}}">
                <b>{{ node.data.name }} {{ childrenCount(node) }}  </b></span>            
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template #loadingTemplate>Loading, please hold....</ng-template>
    </tree-root>
</div>
```

I see [an example from github](https://github.com/500tech/angular-tree-component/blob/master/example/cli/src/app/fulltree/fulltree.component.ts) and I've set `isExpandedField` to `expanded`, however, children fields **are not expanded**:

```
customTemplateStringOptions: any = {
        isExpandedField: 'expanded',
        idField: 'uuid',
        nodeHeight: 23        
    }

public Items: any[];
```

And my data for TreeView looks like this:

[image]

If I add `<tree-node-expander [node]="node"></tree-node-expander>` and click at it, then it expands, but it is now what I want:

```
<tree-root class="panel-body " [nodes]="Items" 
    [options]="customTemplateStringOptions" #tree >
    ...

    <ng-template #treeNodeTemplate let-node>
        <tree-node-expander [node]="node"></tree-node-expander>
        ...
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #loadingTemplate>Loading, please hold....</ng-template>
</tree-root>
```

[image]

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong to expand all children immediately?

Comment: It seems that you just need to call the method `tree.treeModel.expandAll()`

Comment: @Hackerman could you be very kind to show how can I get `tree` to call this function: `tree.treeModel.expandAll()`?

Comment: https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs , it's the method that gets called in the demo, by the `Expand All` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call the `expandAll` method. You can check the demo, here
https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs

The `Expand All` button calls the `tree.treeModel.expandAll()` method.

Comment: It is really strange, but when I click at the button and call this method `tree.treeModel.expandAll`, then it expands. However, if I call this method on `ngInit`, then tree is not expanded.

Comment: If you check this Q&A https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43051335/alternative-to-use-ng-init-in-angular2 it seems that your component needs to implement `OnInit`

Comment: Man, I am so sorry that I promised your reply as answer. Upvoted! It works, but I should create a button and click at this button to expand all nodes. However, I want to expand tree immediately.

Comment: @StepUp You can do this by running `tree.treeModel.expandAll()` in the `(initialized)` event of the tree-root. (https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/events#initialized) `<tree-root (initialized)="onTreeLoad()">` <-- within this method call expandAll

Comment: @LLai I'll try it tomorrow and will write about results. Thank you very much!:)

Comment: @LLai and Hackerman please, see my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47570219/initialized-event-of-angular2-tree-component-is-called-before-loading-data

Answer (score 4):

The angular lifecycle isn't reliable for expanding the tree. The more reliable way is to use the `(initialized)` event on the tree root.

Docs: https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/events#initialized

In your component html file:

`<tree-root (initialized)="onTreeLoad()">`

In your component class:

```
onTreeLoad() {
    this.tree.treeModel.expandAll();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem. I used the below hack which i learned it from using ngx-toastr in ngOnInit. I worked for me. Not sure why ngAfterViewInit is not working for me.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  setTimeout(() => this.tree.treeModel.expandAll(), 500)
}
```

I had to adjust the waiting time to make it work. by animation, you can make it for expansion.

I am still new to angular to provide in depth explanation. Let's see if this works for you and someone provide explanation.

Comment: Not very reliable way of doing this - you're likely to run into race conditions with the browser.