# access native js global object in angular4 or exclude single typescript line from compiling?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-nativescript

In ts I would like to keep a single line of Javascript code native as it is, because it uses a type, which is not known to the tsc (no node_module available) but at runtime it exists in global window object from browser.
Is there an easy solution? (by annotation i.e.).
I use angular4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `any` type if you do not know its type.

```
const foo: any = window.globalVar
```

or

```
const foo = windows.globalVar as any
```

Comment: ok, but want to call a specific method of that object like globalVar.start()

Comment: That's fine, just call it. After declaring as `any`, TypeScript won't complain no matter what you do to it.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43349398/3731501), you can introduce a service for `window` or global variable in order to handle this with DI:

```
export const WINDOW = new OpaqueToken();

...
providers: [..., { provide: WINDOW, useFactory: () => window }]
...

constructor(@Inject(WINDOW) window) {
    window.foo();
}
```

In environments where `window` is unavailable `WINDOW` provider can be replaced with other implementation, e.g. noop `foo`.