# Angular2 router.navigate() not working first time

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have the following routes defined:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuardService] },
    { path: 'sites', component: SiteIndexComponent, resolve: { siteSummaries: SiteSummariesResolve }, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] },
    { path: 'qa-tasks', component: QaTaskIndexComponent, resolve: { investigations: InvestigationsResolve, reviews: ReviewsResolve }, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] },
    { path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

Users of my app see totally different pages based on their role including their "landing" (home) page.  I'm using my HomeComponent to route the user to the correct landing page based on role like this:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    private roles: any;

    constructor(private router: Router,
        private authService: AuthService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        var currentUser = this.authService.getCurrentUser();
        this.roles = currentUser.roles;
        this.redirect();
    }

    private redirect() {
        var route;
        if (this.inRole('site-user-role')) {
            route = 'sites';
        }
        else if (this.inRole('qa-user-role')) {
            route = 'qa-tasks';
        }
        if (route) {
            this.router.navigate([route]);
        }
        else {
            this.router.navigate(['error']);
        }
    }

    private inRole(role) {
        return _.includes(this.roles, role);
    }
}
```

When the `HomeComponent` is first loaded after login, the route does not navigate to, for example, the 'sites' route, but strangely it resolves the siteSummaries dependency.  After the first time it fails to redirect, I can navigate to another route and then try to navigate to the '' route and it correctly redirects to the 'sites' route.

Why is the initial navigation not working?  Based on other similar questions about navigate() not working, I've tried changing my route to '/sites' and './sites', but to no avail.

**Update** 
It looks like it has to do with resolving a dependency for a route.  If redirect to the 'error' route in my `redirect()` function, it does it successfully the first time.  If I add a `resolve` to my 'error' route, it fails to navigate to it the first time.  The odd thing is it makes the HTTP call to fulfill the dependency.  Is this an issue with it not awaiting the return of `navigate()`'s promise?

**Update 2**
Here are the requested classes:

```
export class SiteIndexComponent implements OnInit {

    public siteSummaries: any;
    public totalRegisteredCount: number;
    public totalscreenFailedCount: number;
    public totalinProgressCount: number;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.siteSummaries = this.route.snapshot.data['siteSummaries'];
        this.totalRegisteredCount = this.getTotal('registeredCount');
        this.totalscreenFailedCount = this.getTotal('screenFailedCount');
        this.totalinProgressCount = this.getTotal('inProgressCount');
    }

    private getTotal(prop): number {
        var total = 0;
        _.forEach(this.siteSummaries, function (summary) {
            return total += summary[prop];
        });
        return total;
    }
}

@Injectable()
export class SiteSummariesResolve implements Resolve<any> {

    constructor(private sitesService: SitesService) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
        return this.sitesService.getSiteSummaries();
    }
}

getCurrentUser(): any {
    var currentUser = sessionStorage.getItem('currentUser');
    if (!currentUser) {
        return null;
    }
    return JSON.parse(currentUser);
}
```

**Update 3**
I threw this into my `app.component`:

```
private navigationInterceptor(event: RouterEvent): void {
    if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        console.log('started: ' + JSON.stringify(event));
    }
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        console.log('ended: ' + JSON.stringify(event));
    }
    if (event instanceof NavigationCancel) {
        console.log('cancelled:' + JSON.stringify(event));
    }
    if (event instanceof NavigationError) {
        console.log('error:' + JSON.stringify(event));
    }
}
```

On the times when it fails to load the route (the first time), there is first an event instance of NavigationStart and then an instance of NavigationCancel.  Here is what event looks like on the NavigationCancel:  `{"id":2,"url":"/sites","reason":""}`.  As you can see, no reason is given...

Comment: Is getCurrentUser an async operation?

Comment: Your routing is probably fine. Could you please share `SiteIndexComponent` and `SiteSummariesResolve` ?

Comment: @MezoIstvan Updated

Comment: @DeborahK No, just pulling from `sessionStorage`. I updated the question to include it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I still don't know why it was cancelling my route navigation, but a work around I've come up with is to change `ngInit` to the following:

```
ngOnInit() {
    var currentUser = this.authService.getCurrentUser();
    this.roles = currentUser.roles;
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function () { that.redirect(); }, 50);
}
```

Wrapping my redirect call in a timeout allows things to work as expected with the exception of a imperceptible delay.  It would seem it's some sort of timing issue?  If I try setting the timeout to 20 it also doesn't work.

Comment: With this method I get `ERROR TypeError: this.redirect is not a function` even though  I defined it and use it like this : `private redirect(path: string): void`

Comment: @An-droid note the `that = this`

Comment: This setTimeout work-around worked for me when trying to navigate inside an ```CustomErrorHandler```...

Comment: I was having the same issue. I wrote a custom resolver that converts incoming hash to path and the redirect was firing consistently on all but one of the paths. I'd concur that it's probably some screwy timing issue. If router.navigate somehow gets intercepted because it's taking too long to fire, setTimeout will push it onto the event queue to fire asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

You should not do things with side effects in the constructor. Instead, implement ngOnInit:

```
class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    // navigate things...
  }
}
```

See also: [Difference between Constructor and ngOnInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit)

Comment: Tips: you can try to eliminate the chance of failure inside the redirect logic by debugging with a hardcoded target route.

Comment: Can confirm. Same issue if ngOnInit used.

Answer (score -1):

try this for routing

```html
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


export const router: Routes = [
   { path: '',  redirectTo: 'main', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'main', component:AdminBodyComponent  },
  { path: 'admin', component:AdminComponent  },
  { path: 'posts',component:PostsComponent},
  { path: 'addposts',component:AddPostComponent}];

export const routes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(router);
step2:
inject into your .ts file
constructor(
  private router:Router,
  ...
)
step3:
this.router.navigate(['/addposts']);
```

Comment: Please add an explanation why this code sample solves the problem.