# Ionic model object not loading

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using Ionic 3, and have the following code:

**settings.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar hideBackButton='false' color="primary">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Settings</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

  <div *ngIf="personModel">

    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Notifications</ion-label>
        <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="personModel.notifications" formControlName="notifications" id="notifications" ng-checked="true">Notifications</ion-toggle>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    <br>

    <ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="personModel.milesKm" formControlName="milesKm" id="milesKm">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Km</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="1"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Miles</ion-label>
        <ion-radio value="2"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

  </div>

  <div *ngIf="!personModel" style="text-align:center">
    Please Login to access settings
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

**settings.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, Events, AlertController, IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
import { PersonModel } from '../model/personModel';
import { UtilityService } from '../utils/utilityService';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'settings.html'
})
export class SettingsPage {

  public personModel: PersonModel = null;
  public utilityService: UtilityService = null;

  constructor( @Inject(forwardRef(() => UtilityService)) utilityService, public nav: NavController) {
    this.utilityService = utilityService;
    this.utilityService.getLoggedInPerson().then((data: string) => {
      this.personModel = JSON.parse(data);
    });
  }

}
```

When I access the page, the constructor does populate the `personModel` object. (I add a breakpoint and it does set the object).

So I would expect the page to display the 'Notification' and 'mileKm' list items. But instead it displays:

[image]

This means that at the time the dom loads, the `personModel` object has not loaded yet.

**Question**

How do I get the page to load with the `personModel` loaded?

Thanks

Comment: Suggest sending model data to the page as a navParam rather than getting it in the page itself..

Comment: Thanks. That's a good idea.

Comment: You might consider moving your code from your `constructor` to an Angular lifecylce hook, such as `OnInit` or `AfterViewInit`.  [Here is a good answer related to this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35763811/3055401)