# At what point do classes make instance in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

In Angular projects we can often see classes but we do not see instances or keyword `new`. My question is, at what time does Angular instances classes? At what point does the `constructor` or `ngOnInit()` method run?

Comment: Latter question: [difference between Constructor and OnInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit)

Answer (score 0):

They're instantiated (and thus the constructor is run) when they need to be.

For example, a component is instantiated when the component needs to be rendered, either by being routed to, or invoked via `<some-component>` in some template. A service is instantiated when it needs to be provided.

`ngOnInit` is a life-cycle hook particular to components. You can read more about it vs. constructors in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit).