# Understanding how Angular initialises app and creates DOM elements

Tags: angular

Say I have a button:

```
<button (click)="clicked()" class="but">Click2</button>
```

And component:

```
export class AppComponent {

    but = document.querySelector('.but');

    clicked(){
      console.log(this.but);
    } 

    constructor(){
    }
```

Console output is null here, because the button in DOM is not created yet, right? But why I can use its `clicked()` function if it is not created yet..?

Comment: Obviously because you bind `click` event on button element

Comment: you cannot access the`DOM` like this in angular , if you need to access the `DOM` elements you need to use `Elementref` and `viewChild` and then you can add properties or attributes using `Rederer2`

Comment: clicked() function will be triggered, but it will display undefined or an empty array.

Comment: `document.querySelector('.but')` is executed when `AppComponent` is instantiated, but at this time the DOM isn't rendered yet. As Rahul mentioned, you should avoid accessing the DOM using `document.querySelector` in Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this question is a continuation of your another question [Why I can't access template DOM element in the constructor of the component](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45464973/2545680). There you had the following:

```
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(){
        button : HTMLElement = document.querySelector('button');
        refreshClickStream$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.button, 'click').subscribe();
    }
```

> Console output is null here, because the button in DOM is not created
>   yet, right?

And you are right about that as  I explained in the mentioned answer.

> But why I can use its clicked() function if it is not created yet..?

It's because Angular **when constructing view nodes** for the `AppComponent` will bind to the `click` event of the button. Since Angular creates these DOM elements it knows when it has to subscribe.

This all happens inside [createViewNodes](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/view/view.ts#L239) function:

```
function createViewNodes(view) {
    for (var i = 0; i < def.nodes.length; i++) {
        var nodeDef = def.nodes[i];
        switch (nodeDef.flags) {
            case 1 /* TypeElement */:
                var el = (createElement(view, renderHost, nodeDef));
                ...
                listenToElementOutputs(view, componentView, nodeDef, el); <--------------
```