# What is the significance of ngOnInit() in Angular?

Tags: angular, ngoninit

Can we not perform all the same operations it does in the constructor?

Comment: There is an answer on this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit

Comment: The differences between `ngOnInit()` and constructors notwithstanding, executing complex logic in a constructor is definitely an antipattern

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Constructor and ngOnInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit)

Answer (score 1):

> `ngOnInit` is a life cycle hook called by Angular to indicate that
> Angular is done creating the component.
>
> The Constructor is a default method of the class that is executed when
> the class is instantiated and ensures proper initialization of fields
> in the class and its subclasses.

Someone give a really good explanation here [Difference between Constructor and ngOnInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit)