# Init in constructor and logic/function in ngOnInit()

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have read on `constructor` and `ngOnInit`. And myself have came to a conclusion that we should make variable and service initialization in `constructor` and any logic in `ngOnInit`. And this seems clean to me.

Here is my sample of implementation. Hope to get some feedback if i am doing it right or i am understanding the `constructor` and `ngOnInit` wrongly. Or should i just put everything on `ngOnInit` instead.

```
constructor(
    public loading: LoadingController,
    public auth: AuthService,
    public data: DataService
) {
    this.existingProfile = new EventEmitter<Profile>();
    this.loader = this.loading.create({
        content: 'Loading...'
    });
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.loader.present();
    this.data.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
        this.userProfile = profile;
        this.existingProfile.emit(this.userProfile);
        this.loader.dismiss();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've described the difference between `constructor` and `ngOnInit` in the article [The essential difference between Constructor and ngOnInit in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-essential-difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit-in-angular-c9930c209a42)
in great details and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit/45430181#45430181).

If your initialization depends on the `@Input` bindings then you have only one choice - `ngOnInit` - since bindings are not available in the constructor. If it's not dependent, then it's perfectly fine to perform initialization in the constructor. In fact, if you use outputs then this:

```
class O {
    @Output ev = new EventEmitter();
```

is still compiled to

```
class O {
    constructor() {
        this.ev = new EventEmitter();
```

However, the general recommendation is to use `ngOnInit` for initialization. In this way everybody on your team knows to look inside `ngOnInit` to understand how this component is initialized.

So as you see it's a bit subjective if there's no dependency on `ngOnInit`.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. +1

Comment: @sebaferreras, you're welcome! make sure to read the article I linked)

Comment: Of course, I follow you on Medium so I always read your posts :)

Comment: @sebaferreras, glad to hear that! Good luck!