# Display Json Array Angular 5 HttpClient

Tags: json, httpclient, frontend, display, angular5

I'm a beginner in Angular5 and I need your help...

I made an API in my backend (Java/Spring Boot) which I can access with `http://localhost:8080/applications`

With this API I want to retrieve a chunk of data (it's a JSON Array).

[image]

I try to retrieve data with httpClient on my Angular but I have this result in my frontend : [object Object]

[image]

This my **app.component.ts**

```
    import {Component, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
    import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse} from "@angular/common/http";
    import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
    })

    export class AppComponent {
      url = 'http://localhost:8080/applications';
      res = [];

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      }


      ngOnInit(): void {

        this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(data => {
            this.res = data;
            console.log(data);
        },
          (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            if (err.error instanceof Error) {
              console.log("Client-side error occured.");
            } else {
              console.log("Server-side error occured.");
            }
          });

      }

    }
```

My Application interface **Application.ts**

```
    interface Applications {

      id : number;
      type : string;
      port : string;
      baseUrl : string;
      architecture : string;
      protocol : string;
      serveur : string;

    }
```

How can I display my data ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Close enough, try this:
in your app.component.ts you can just use the constructor with dependency injection, no need of [ngOnInit()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35763811/2473163). One more thing, I'm not sure about your API Route. You should have something like http://localhost:8080/[controller]/[action]
http://localhost:8080/application/getall
http://localhost:8080/api/application/getall --> this one is used for this example.

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http  from '@angular/http';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'] })

export class AppComponent {
private url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/application/getall'
public apps: Applications[];

constructor(http: Http) {
    http.get(url).subscribe(result => {
        this.apps = result.json() as Applications[];
    }, error => console.error(error));
}}

interface Applications {
   id: number;
   type: string;
   port: string;
   baseUrl: string;
   architecture: string;
   protocol: string;
   serveur: string; }
```

in your app.component.html let try with an unordered list

```
<ul *ngIf="apps">
   <li *ngFor="let app of apps">
      {{app.Id}}
   </li>
</ul>
```

Put `<app-root></app-root>` where you want in your html to make the call.

One more step, in your app.shared.module.ts you have to import your
component      `import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';` and add your component to @NgModule declarations[]

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   //...
   AppComponent
  ]
  //...
```

I hope this works

Answer (score 2):

Hi #yupii7 thanks a lot to answer me.
I try your code but it doesn't work in Angular5.
But, when I simply use :

```
    public apps: Applications[];

    this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(result => {
            this.apps = result as Applications[];
        }
```

It works perfectly :)

Now, I need to find a way to push these data on a table. If you have an idea I will be happy to hear it. :)

**See here !**
To add a comment on yours I need 50 reputation, so I leave my comment here to make you see it.
You need to ask a new question. See [angular material](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) or make your own [table](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)

Answer (score -1):

You can simply do that by using angular pipes if you just need to see data
In view

```
<div>
{{res|json}}
</div>
```