# Apply onclick only for child items

Tags: angular

How can i apply onclick for every item within div element

```
<div>
<p (click)="Click(1)" value="1">1 element</p>
<p (click)="Click(2)" value="2">2 element</p>
<p (click)="Click(3)" value="3">3 element</p>
</div>
```

As you see, i showed the very bad way, is there any clearier and simpler method to do that.
BTW. list inside div is dynamic

Comment: There is a section in my answer for another question that can help you. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47917853/2473163)

Answer (score 1):

@Dakito try this...   make an Array as `values` and then

```
    <div>
      <p (click)="Click(value)" *ngFor="let value of values" value="value">{{value}} element</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript Class

```
items = [{ number: 1 }, { number: 2 }, { number: 3 }];
```

Template:

```
<div>
    <p *ngFor="let item of items" 
        (click)="Click(item.number)" 
        [value]="item.number">
        {{item.number}} element
    </p>
</div>
```