# Pass Angular Observable to ASP MVC via HTTPGET

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc

On the HTML, when you click the **exportok()** button below, I wish to send the current year (aka.2020) from the selected dropdown to the.NET MVC Controller function called EXPORT via a HTTPGET call `"/api/stations/export”.`

Admin.component.ts

```
exportyears = [
    {name: '1 July 2019 to 30 June 2020', id: '2019-2020'},
    {name: '1 July 2020 to 30 June 2021', id: '2020-2021'},
  ];
```

Admin.component.html

```
<form>
  <select formControlName="exportyear" [(ngModel)]="reportyear"(change)="onClickMe()">
    <option 
      *ngFor="let exportyear of exportyears" [ngValue]="exportyears"
    >
      {{ exportyear.id }}
    </option>
  </select>
</form>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" (click)="exportOk(exportyears[0].id)">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>&nbsp;OK</button>
```

Service.ts

```
export(reportyear: string): Observable<Response> {
  
//  let headers = new Headers();
  //   headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
 // headers.append('reportyear', reportyear);

  let request = new Request({
    method: RequestMethod.Get,
    url: environment.baseUrl + "/api/stations/export",
    responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob,
    body: {reportyear}
  }
);
```

Station.ts

```
exportOk(reportyear: string) {
  this.exporting = true;
  this.exportMessage = null;

  this.stationsService.export(reportyear)
    .subscribe(
      (res: Response) => {
        this.exporting = false;
        this.exportModal.hide();
        Utils.launchAttachment(res);
      },
      error => {
        this.exporting = false;
        if (error.error) {
          this.exportMessage = error.error;
        }
        else {
          this.exportMessage = error;
        }
      }
    );
```

ASP.NET MVC Controller
Controller.cs

```
[HttpGet("export")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Export([FromBody]string reportyear)
  {
    var obj = reportyear; //show me the year so I can use it further down the line…..
    var stations = await stationRepository.GetExportAsync();
    ......
  }
```

Comment: Do you have any error like 500 or 400 ? If not then it must be between what you send (url/data) and the controller action. You should have something like this at the end: "/api/stations/export/2019-2020” right ? Try this    [HttpGet("year")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Export(string year)
        { ... }

Comment: What is in the HttpGet parenthesis must be the same as the one in the function parameters. Try with curly brackets: [HttpGet("{year}")].

Comment: Thanks Sinan. The error i get is :5000/api/stations/export:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 (Unsupported Media Type). will  try  [HttpGet("export {year}")]. Which i think is because its not recognising the header.

Comment: OK now i updated to [HttpGet("export{reportyear}")] and I get a 404 Not Found.

Comment: in your url -> https://localhost:5000/api/stations/export, stations is your controller name and export is the action. So your function name must be Export, until here every is ok. It not  [HttpGet("export {year}")] but  [HttpGet("{year}")].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have something like this, it may help you.

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Find a product by name
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Name"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet("{name}")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetByName(string name)
    {
        try
        {
            var item = await _productService.GetOneByName(name);

            if (item != null)
            {
                return Ok(item);
            }
            return NotFound();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message.ToJson());
        }
    }
```

you can see that what is in the curly brackets [HttpGet("{name}")] matches what is in the function parameters GetByName(string name). Btw, I suggest you to use postman for debugging your api if you don't.

**UPDATE**
try this:

```
export(reportyear: string): Observable<Response> {

let request = new Request(
   {
      method: RequestMethod.Get,
      url: environment.baseUrl + "/api/stations/export" + "/" + reportyear,
      responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob
   }
);
```

Comment: Thanks Sian. I get what your saying now. Ive updated the MVC controller to                  [HttpGet("{reportyear}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Export(string reportyear) but im still getting a 404. will check out Postman too

Comment: Ok, so it means that there is nothing that matches your request from the database.

Comment: Not yet, i  still get a 404. The Angular function is (click)="exportOk(exportyears[0].id). But i can see what you mean, it needed the {reportyear}

Comment: exactly ! your are close enough.

Comment: i think i need to rework this                                                                                              export(reportyear: string): Observable<Response> {

        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('reportyear', reportyear);

        let request = new Request({
            method: RequestMethod.Get,
            url: environment.baseUrl + "/api/stations/export",
            responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob
        }
      );

Comment: Are you trying to insert data to your database with "export" ? If so then you need to use httppost. I found a kind of related answer that I posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47908637/display-json-array-angular-5-httpclient/47917853#47917853

Comment: Thanks Sinan. Im not inserting any data, when you click the export button, i wish to send in the year parameter) so I can start an excel import. When i changed the MVC view to                      [httpGet("export")] it recognises my controller and hits the function breakpoint, however the public async Task<IActionResult> Export(string reportyear) is not recognising the report year. Is this because Angular code above (export(reportyear: string): Observable<Response> {} isnt working?

Comment: so something like this? export(reportyear: string): Observable<Response> {

        let headers = new Headers();    
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('reportyear', reportyear);

        let request = new Request({
            method: RequestMethod.Get,
            url: environment.baseUrl + "/api/stations/export",
            responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob, {headers: headers})
        }
        );

Comment: Ive edited the original JSON with the body response but it's still not working. Any suggestions please? I can see the year value isn't null in the function but the MVC Controller cannot see the year value (although the MVC controller hits the breakpoint in the function now).

Comment: Sup Michael :) If you update your code then you should edit your main question with a section named UPDATE in bold and paste your code with some new information.

Comment: Btw if your request type is a GET then you can't have a body. So remove that one. Here a link about REQUEST: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request

Comment: If you have multiple data to send with the get request then you will have something like this: http://localhost:5000/api/stations/export?quesrystring   where querystring look like this: field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3

Comment: I changed the Service.ts try that.

Comment: Thanks Sinan for your help. Both your suggestions helped me get this to work. I needed to update my MVC view as follows:  [HttpGet("export/{reportyear}")] and needed to add the Angular parameter like you suggested: url: environment.baseUrl + "/api/stations/export" + "/" + reportyear and now the end result is a string value in my MVC controller that matches my dropdown selection from the Angular application. Thankyou :) I can't believe i missed that.