# What is the difference if I create something in constructor vs ngOnInit?

Tags: angular

I created a form by calling a function from the constructor

```
constructor(private userManagementService: UserManagementService, private fb:FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm(){
    this.signupForm = this.fb.group({
      firstName:['',Validators.required], 
      lastName:['',Validators.required],
      email:['',Validators.required],
      password:['',Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

I suppose I could also create the form in ngOnInit

```
constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) {

  }


ngOnInit{

    this.signupForm = this.fb.group({
      firstName:['',Validators.required], 
      lastName:['',Validators.required],
      email:['',Validators.required],
      password:['',Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

}

What is the difference between the two approaches? Is one better than the other?

Comment: Please go through this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit

Comment: I provided [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48705981/3731501) in duplicate question instead that addresses your concerns, i.e. practical differences between those two methods. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sometimes I feel like people think Stackoverflow is Google search or something...

Answer (score 2):

**Constructor :**

> The constructor method on an ES6 class (or TypeScript in this case) is
>   a feature of a class itself, rather than an Angular feature. It’s out
>   of Angular’s control when the constructor is invoked, which means that
>   it’s not a suitable hook to let you know when Angular has finished
>   initialising the component.

**ngOnInit :**

> ngOnInit is purely there to give us a signal that Angular has finished
>   initialising the component , The ngOnInit lifecycle hook is a
>   guarantee that your bindings are readily available.

Here is the great article about it in detail : **[READ](https://toddmotto.com/angular-constructor-ngoninit-lifecycle-hook)**

There are lot more discussion upon this like :

[Difference between Constructor and ngOnInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit)

https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-essential-difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit-in-angular-c9930c209a42