# Route by adding listener if standing at same component Angular 4

Tags: angular, routes

I would navigate between two products, `localhost:4200/products/444` to `localhost:4200/products/555`.

The url changes when I navigate between them but nothing happened to the DOM, I'm still stuck at `444` product and the url is `555`.

I'm using Angular 4

Comment: please let us see your code.

Comment: Are you sure there is no exception in the browser, open the developer console and check for errors

Answer (score 1):

It's because Angular reuses the component.

You have to subscribe to the route params to listen for changes and update the view accordingly.

```
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      // put the logic of your component here
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your component look like this :

You must have called your function from `constructor`.

You need to get ID and call the function from `ngOnInit`.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-comp',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
      this.myFunction(this.myID); // Remove this line from constructor     
    }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.myID = params['id'];
      this.myFunction(this.myID); // Add your function call in ngOnInit
    });
  }
}
```

To know the difference between `constructor` and `ngOnInit` please [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit)