# When is the Typescript constructor called in Angular? How does it work with multiple instances of the same component?

Tags: angular

I have a dynamic tab based component. Each time a new tab is created, a new instance of the component (with its view, dependencies and state) needs to be instantiated.

My question is how does the constructor work in this instance? Is the component instantiated multiple times - thus constructor called multiple times? Or will it be called only once and I have to manage state using onInit and other lifecycle hooks?

Comment: From my understanding each component created is it's own instances. So for every "new tab" (component) is a new instance.

Comment: I don't know the answer for sure; but you should be able to quickly find out with some console logs; right?

Answer (score 1):

Every component is a different instance with a different lifecycle and its own behaviour.

Related informations can you find in: 
[Difference between Constructor and ngOnInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit)