# Google Authentication in Angular 6

Tags: angular, google-authentication, angular6

I have created a project in angular 6 which exhibits google authentication using [angular-6-social-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-6-social-login). Following is the install command:

```
npm install --save angular-6-social-login
```

After this, i made the following changes to the **app.module.ts** file:

```
import {SocialLoginModule,AuthServiceConfig,GoogleLoginProvider} from "angular-6-social-login";


// Configs 
export function getAuthServiceConfigs() {
  let config = new AuthServiceConfig(
  [
    {
      id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      provider: new GoogleLoginProvider("Your-Google-Client-Id")
    }
  ];
 );
 return config;
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
   ...
  SocialLoginModule
 ],
 providers: [
   ...
  {
  provide: AuthServiceConfig,
  useFactory: getAuthServiceConfigs
  }
 ],
 bootstrap: [...]
})


export class AppModule { }
```

And the following changes in **app.component.ts**:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {
 AuthService,
 GoogleLoginProvider
} from 'angular-6-social-login';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signin',
  templateUrl: './signin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signin.component.css']
})


export class SigninComponent implements OnInit {

constructor( private socialAuthService: AuthService ) {}

public socialSignIn(socialPlatform : string) {
  let socialPlatformProvider;
  if(socialPlatform == "facebook"){
      socialPlatformProvider = FacebookLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID;
   }else if(socialPlatform == "google"){
     socialPlatformProvider = GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID;
   }else if (socialPlatform == "linkedin") {
     socialPlatformProvider = LinkedinLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID;
   }

this.socialAuthService.signIn(socialPlatformProvider).then(
  (userData) => {
    console.log(socialPlatform+" sign in data : " , userData);
    // Now sign-in with userData
    // ...

     }
   );
 }

 }
```

Following is my **app.component.html**

```
<button (click)="socialSignIn('google')">Sign in with Google</button>
```

I started the application and it runs fine. Although i get the following error in the console:

[Error that the console displays when i start the application. Basically when i run ng serve --open and open the console window of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cm4AL.png)

The application runs fine, that is on click of the button, a google login screen pops up, asking me for my google credentials. I enter them and its authenticates.

I have 3 issues or rather doubts:
1) Why is that error appearing?

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'signIn' 
of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'signIn' of undefined
at angular-6-social-login.umd.js:250
at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone.js:891)
at GoogleLoginProvider.push../node_modules/angular-6-social-login/angular-6- 
social-login.umd.js.GoogleLoginProvider.signIn (angular-6-social- 
login.umd.js:249)
```

2) We have exported **function getAuthServiceConfigs()** and later declared it in the Providers array in **app.module.ts**. Whats the use of that?

3) I need to render the google login screen on start of the application i.e. without clicking on the button. How do i achieve that?

I tried calling the method in ngOnInit():

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.socialSignIn('google');
}
```

but the screen appears blank

Please help me with this!

Answer (score 0):

If the code you have posted for app.module.ts is literally what you are trying to run, please note that the constructor for `GoogleLoginProvider()` within `getAuthServiceConfigs() {...new GoogleLoginProvider("Your-Google-Client-Id")...}` is expecting you to populate it with your Google Client ID.

More specifically, please note that the client ID will look something like `YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com` where `YOUR_CLIENT_ID` will be a long list of digits and numbers given to you by the Google API console. This whole string `YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com` must be given to the `GoogleLoginProvider() constructor`.... again, with `YOUR_CLIENT_ID` replaced with your web site client ID from the Google API console.

If you need to obtain a client ID from Google, you can follow the following link and click the blue CONFIGURE A PROJECT button: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

I hope that helps.
Best wishes.

Comment: Yes, i have added  the client id i received when i configured a project. Still it shows     ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'signIn' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'signIn' of undefined
    at angular-6-social-login.umd.js:250

Comment: Rahul were you able to find solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is this

```
ngOnInit(){
 this.socialSignIn('google');
}
```

The injected `socialAuthService` of `SigninComponent` is not available on `ngOnInit()`. You can see more in [Difference between Constructor and ngOnInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit)

Since I see a button on app.component.html. If you are trying to simulate a mouse click I would suggest using the appropriate [Lifecycle Hooks](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/components/lifecycle-hooks/)

Also, delete `FacebookLoginProvider` and `LinkedInLoginProvider` in `app.component.ts` since there are no imports and no mention in `app.module.ts`