# Can't resolve all parameters for TemlComponent: (?). at syntaxError (compiler.js:1016)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

Im new to Angular and Im trying to find out where Im going wrong with this and why Im getting this error.

Can't resolve all parameters for TemlComponent: (?).     at syntaxError (compiler.js:1016).

I have created a working example here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w8jyjs with all the pertinent files.

The code probably contains several redundant items and methods that I created while attempting to fix this.  removing a;ll parameters from the constructor  in teml.component.ts gets rid of the error.

Guidance to what i've done wrong here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `constructor` property in Angular is meant for defining dependencies for the initialisation of your component and **not** for declaring a property, which explains why you're getting the error.

Consider using an `@Input()` instead.

Here's an updated [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t5ygjo?file=src/app/teml.component.ts).

---

EDIT: For more info about constructors in Angular, check out this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35763811).

Comment: you did it by the time I fixed the error. anyway glad you could help him

Comment: @VithuBati Could you clarify what you mean by your comment?

Answer (score 0):

So this was entirely a result of my inexperience and trying to apply examples without full knowledge.  I appreciate the feedback and quick answer.
I was trying to use the constuctor to pass a parameter which is not the correct way in Typescript.