# TypeScript Difference in Class Property Initial Value

Tags: typescript, class

In TypeScript, is there any difference between giving the class property its initial value on definition vs in the constructor?

```
class Car {
  engine = 'hybrid';
}
```

VS.

```
class Car {
  engine: string;
  constructor() {
    this.engine = 'hybrid';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example, when the code transpiled to JS - there is no difference (see @Gil's answer).

In TypeScript actually there is a difference (but not in your example, since your constructor does not have any arguments).
If you want to pass arguments to the constructor class - then the magic of TypeScript happens because TS includes a concise way to create and assign a class instance property from a constructor parameter.

Let's say we have a class:

```
class MyClass {
  private prop: string;

  constructor(prop: string) {
    this.prop = prop;
  }
}
```

You can write it in ONE line of code adding property modificators:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(private prop: string) { }
}
```

This will create `prop` property in the class and also initialize it with new value from constructor argument. Define `private/public/protected` modificators is up to you (it depends on your class's logic).

Last case - if you don't set modificator:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(prop: string) {
    // prop variable is available here
  }
  // prop variable is not available outside the constructor method
}
```

Comment: [There is a difference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27644) now

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between both of those options. 
When compiling both of the code versions you provided you will get the same result:

```js
var Car = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Car() {
        this.engine = 'hybrid';
    }
    return Car;
}());
```

You can check it by yourself in [TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/).

Comment: That's Awesome, Thanx!

Comment: [There is a difference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27644) now

Answer (score 0):

Prefer constructor. Its purpose is to initialise variables. Somebody looking at your code might first look at the constructor to see initialised values

Comment: Refer this to know the differences between them - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit

Comment: Nandu's link above refers to Constructor vs ngOnInit, not what OP is asking about.