# Set default value of boolean typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, boolean

I have an object:

```
export class ReccurrenceModel {
    fromDate: Date;
    toDate: Date;
    weeklyReccurrence: number;
    state: State;
    isMonday: boolean;
    isTuesday: boolean;
    isWednesday: boolean;
    isThursday: boolean;
    isFriday: boolean;
    fromDateToReturn: Date;
    toDateToReturn: Date;
}
```

I use it like this

```
  if (this.reccurrenceSelected === true) {
      this.reccurrence.isMonday = this.mondaySelected;
      this.reccurrence.isTuesday = this.tuesdaySelected;
      this.reccurrence.isWednesday = this.wednesdaySelected;
      this.reccurrence.isThursday = this.thursdaySelected;
      this.reccurrence.isFriday = this.fridaySelected;
}
```

I want to set a default value for them - false because if I do not set them in  in UI, they will be undefined and I don't want that.

How to set de default value of a boolean in typescript?

Comment: try ```isMonday:boolean = false;```

Comment: may be `variabelName = false`, is it?

Comment: @FatemeFazli this gives a lint error for redundancy (just to inform)

Comment: @FatemeFazli also this is not recommended way

Comment: @trichetriche , PardeepJain thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Doesn't make any big change in UI level you can use either. Both are falsy values for UI.

You can set anyone.

```
variableName = false
```

or

```
variableName: boolean;
```

`variableName` you can use either UI consider it as false by default untill you assign its value to true.

Answer (score 6):

I would add a default constructor and do something like this :

```
export class ReccurrenceModel {
    fromDate: Date;
    toDate: Date;
    weeklyReccurrence: number;
    state: State;
    isMonday: boolean;
    isTuesday: boolean;
    isWednesday: boolean;
    isThursday: boolean;
    isFriday: boolean;
    fromDateToReturn: Date;
    toDateToReturn: Date;

    constructor(){
      this.isMonday = false;
      this.isTuesday = false;
      this.isWednesday = false;
      this.isThursday = false;
      this.isFriday = false;
    }
}
```

later i would do something like this : ,

```
this.reccurrence = new ReccurrenceModel();
```

The above line would initialize the required fields.
you can confirm this by doing a `console.log(this.reccurrence)` after calling the `constructor`

Answer (score 5):

`undefined`, as well as `false`, are both falsy values that you can test the same way.

But default values are set with

```
export class ReccurrenceModel {
    fromDate: Date;
    toDate: Date;
    weeklyReccurrence: number;
    state: State;
    isMonday = false;
    isTuesday = false;
    ...
    fromDateToReturn: Date;
    toDateToReturn: Date;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `getters` and `setters` in class

```
export class ReccurrenceModel {
    fromDate: Date;
    toDate: Date;
    weeklyReccurrence: number;
    state: State;
    isMonday: boolean;
    isTuesday: boolean;
    isWednesday: boolean;
    isThursday: boolean;
    isFriday: boolean;
    fromDateToReturn: Date;
    toDateToReturn: Date;
        ...

        get fromDate() {
            return this.fromDate|| "";
        }
        get isMonday() {
            return this.isMonday|| false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put

```
      this.isMonday = false;
      this.isTuesday = false;
      this.isWednesday = false;
      this.isThursday = false;
      this.isFriday = false;
```

these in  ngOnInit() method also, this is the method which is called first.
to find the difference between  ngOnInit() and constructor visit [Difference between Constructor and ngOnInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit)