# What is difference between constructor and ngOnInIt?

Tags: javascript, angular

It seems to be similar functions, what are the main differences and purposes of them

//Code

```
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
constructor(){


}

ngOnInit(){

}
```

Comment: See: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: contructor is a class constructor, `ngOnInit` is an Angular hook. The main difference is `@Input`s will be resolved on `ngOnInit`, but not in contructor. Also search the web before posting questions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Constructor and ngOnInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit)

Answer (score 0):

People have already mentioned life cycle hooks so I won't talk about that.
However, Angular docs state that in the constructor you should only do lightweight operations such as simple sync variable assignments.

In ngOnInit you should do more heavy lifting operations such as HTTP requests, etc