# How to append after last child element with Angular Renderer2?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-renderer2

I'm trying to append a button after an input field with an Angular7 directive. The problem is that the Renderer2 method appendChild is placing the button before the input field.

[Button before input field image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTKRJ.jpg)

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input , HostListener, Renderer2, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appInlineEdit2]'
})
export class InlineEdit2Directive {

  @Input() value: any;
  private spanElement: Node;
  private spanText: Node;
  // private children: Node[];

  constructor(private el: ElementRef,
    public renderer: Renderer2) {
      this.spanElement = this.renderer.createElement('span');
      // this.spanText = this.renderer.createText('dummy_span');
      // this.renderer.appendChild(this.spanElement, this.spanText);
      this.renderer.setAttribute(this.spanElement, 'id', 'anchor');
      this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, this.spanElement);
      // this.renderer.insertBefore(this.el.nativeElement, this.spanElement, null);
      this.renderer.listen(this.spanElement, 'click', this.onClick.bind(this));

      const button = this.renderer.createElement('button');
      this.renderer.setAttribute(button, 'type', 'button');
      this.renderer.addClass(button, 'btn');
      this.renderer.addClass(button, 'btn-primary');
      const buttonText = this.renderer.createText('OK');
      this.renderer.appendChild(button, buttonText);
      this.renderer.listen(button, 'click', this.onClickOK.bind(this));
      this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, button);
      // this.renderer.insertBefore(this.el.nativeElement, button, null);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      console.log(this.el.nativeElement.childNodes);
      // this.showMode();
    }
}
```

And in the template:

```
<div class="input-group col-6" appInlineEdit2 [value]="model">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username"
        [(ngModel)]="model" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
</div>
```

I expect the button to be after the input field in the DOM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are executing `Renderer2` related logic in constructor. Constructor is called during component creation and at that moment component DOM has not been initialized yet, which means `ElementRef` and `nativeElement` exists somewhere but not in the DOM yet. That's why you are experiencing such ambiguous behavior.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit) for further details.

So, placing `Renderer2` related logic within `ngOnInit` solves your problem.

Here is a working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ywn1ky