# Testing a method that uses observable on the constructor

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine

I need to cover this method with Jasmine in my code

```
private subject = new Subject<any>();

getMessage(): Observable<any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
```

Here is my constructor

```
fiscalDocument: FiscalDocumentData;
subscription: Subscription;

constructor(private _myFiscalDocumentsService: MyFiscalDocumentsService) {  
    this.subscription = this._myFiscalDocumentsService.getMessage().subscribe(message => {
      if (message) {
        this.fiscalDocument = message;

      } else {
        this.fiscalDocument = null;
      } 
    });

  }
```

I've already tried to do that in my test, I have the TestBed.confiugreTestingModule, but I won't post here because I believe that's my problem isn't there

```
let dummyOb: Observable<any>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    service = TestBed.get(MyFiscalDocumentsService);
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyFiscalDocumentsDetailsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should getMessage', async () => {
    let generalSpy = spyOn(service, 'getMessage' ).and.returnValue(await Promise.resolve(dummyOb));
    expect(generalSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
 });
```

**The error message: Expected spy getMessage to have been called.**
**EDIT: I got the if condition, now I'm trying the else**

Answer (score 1):

It is bad practice use some complex logic in constructor, use ngOnInit instead: [Difference between Constructor and ngOnInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit/35763811#35763811)

Comment: I'm making just the layout, that's why I'm using the constructor just to show the screen functioning

Comment: And thanks for the help with the difference between constructor and ngOnInit

Answer (score 1):

By the time you create a spy your constructor has already been called in `beforeEach`.
Try this:

```js
let dummyOb: Observable<any>;

it('should getMessage', async () => {
    let generalSpy = spyOn(service, 'getMessage' ).and.returnValue(await Promise.resolve(dummyOb));
    new MyFiscalDocumentsDetailsComponent(service);
    expect(generalSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, In this exact moment I got a solution in this way
`it('should getMessage', async () => {
    let spy = spyOn(service, 'getMessage').and.callThrough();
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });`
Now I'm trying to resolve the else condition

Answer (score 0):

I resolved in this way, an if-else condition wasn't necessary

Component

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = this._myFiscalDocumentsService.getMessage().subscribe(message => {
    this.fiscalDocument = message;
  });
}
```

Spec

```js
it('should getMessage', async () => {
    service.subject.next(dummyMock)
    const spy = spyOn(service, 'getMessage').and.returnValue(of(dummyMock));
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(component.subscription).toBeDefined();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```