# Angular 8: Using HttpClient.get.toPromise

Tags: angular, promise, httpclient

From a service constructor, I want to call 2 HttpClient.get asynchronously.
When the constructor is completed, the 2 get requests have to be already completed.

```html
public async ReadConfiguration () 
  {
      await this.http.get ('http://localhost:80/api/Target.xml',{ responseType: 'text' })
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => { console.log ('error');
        });

      console.log ('line 25');

      await this.http.get ('http://localhost:80/api/Target.xml',{ responseType: 'text' })
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => { console.log ('error');
        });

      console.log ('line 32');
  }

  /*************************************************************************************/
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    console.log ('-->constructor');
    this.ReadConfiguration ();
    console.log ('Done');
    console.log ('<--constructor');

  }
```

On the console I got:

```
-->constructor <br/>
Done <br/>
<--constructor <br/>
```

and only then (after few constructors are executed) I got the data.

Can you please tell what is wrong in my code ?

Thank you in advance,
Zvika

Comment: Can you tell me what you want to achieve? as code is working fine, for explanation read out my answer below.

Comment: You cant use async / await on constructor.
You can use promises only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of using the constructor is to create the component and to initiate the variables

In your case you are looking for what we called it a 'HOOK' as ngOnInit that is executed after the Constructor.

Please look at this :  [Difference between Constructor and ngOnInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit)

And For the Synchronicity which may depends on the response time of your API i suggest you to make the two calls as a nested call, i mean one can be inside the other as bellow :

```
await this.http.get ('http://localhost:80/api/Target.xml',{ responseType: 'text' })
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => {

 await this.http.get ('http://localhost:80/api/Target.xml',{ responseType: 'text' })
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => { console.log ('error');
        });

})
        .catch(err => { console.log ('error');
        });
```

Comment: Hi Youssef. Calling my ReadConfiguration from ngOnInit is a great idea. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, code is working fine.

Because your method `this.ReadConfiguration();` is asynchronous in nature, and it will run out of the normal flow and execute after some time which is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use your readconfiguration function your gonna need to use it like this:

```
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
       console.log ('-->constructor');
       this.ReadConfiguration().then(data => {
       console.log('done')
       console.log ('<--constructor');
       });
    }
```

and your function maybe something like this:

```
public async ReadConfiguration () 
  {
      await this.http.get ('http://localhost:80/api/Target.xml',{ responseType: 'text' })
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => { console.log ('error');
        });

      console.log ('line 25');

      await this.http.get ('http://localhost:80/api/Target.xml',{ responseType: 'text' })
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => { console.log ('error');
        });

      console.log ('line 32');
    Promise.reslove();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Youssef Tounoussi stated above, put the `ReadConfiguration` call in `async ngOnInit()`.
  In addition, to avoid the nested promise responses, you could rearrange the calls as shown below:

```
public async ReadConfiguration()
  {
    let res: string; 
    try
    {
      // 1st call
      res = await this.http.get('http://localhost:80/api/Target.xml', { responseType: 'text' }).toPromise();
      console.log(res);

      // 2nd call
      res = await this.http.get('http://localhost:80/api/Target.xml', { responseType: 'text' }).toPromise();
      console.log(res);

    } catch (error)
    {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  async ngOnInit()
  {
    // ...
    await this.ReadConfiguration();
    // ..
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to put an await in this line:

```
this.ReadConfiguration ();
```

Like this:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
   console.log ('-->constructor');
   await this.ReadConfiguration ();
   console.log ('Done');
   console.log ('<--constructor');
}
```

Comment: you cant use async await on constructors.