# Is there a way to execute an asynchronous request after every login without influencing performance?

Tags: angular

At the start of my application(after login, each reload), i would like to load(API-request) a logo in the background which im going to need later on. Is there a way to let it load in the background without it affecting the performance?

I tried to execute the request inside the `app.component.ts` because thats the one class which gets executed right at the start:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private oAuthService: OAuthService, private logoService: LogoService) {

    // a lot of configs...

    this.oAuthService.configure(config);
    this.oAuthService.setStorage(sessionStorage);
    this.oAuthService.tryLogin({}).then();

    this.logoService.getLogo().subscribe(logo => {
      // save logo somewhere
    }
  }
}
```

But this ended up slowing down the first loading process. Why is that? Isnt the request just happening asynchronously in the background?

Comment: How did you measure, that it is slower? with isStable?

Comment: can this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit

Comment: @Stefan I didnt measure it, its like half a second slower so its easy to see without having to measure. But i think i described the problem wrong. What takes longer isnt the time till the first component is loaded, its the time till the api-requests the first loaded component does are finished. And thats probably because of the picture being downloaded in the background which utilizes the bandwidth?