# How to fix "Cannot set property of undefined"?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular9

I am making a countdown timer in angular but getting an TypeError while trying to call a variable from another component. I am not able to figure what exactly is causing this problem. This is the video I am follow: [Countdown Timer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtvcJ1BQOxI) Below is my code:

**Timer.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-timer',
  template: `<span>{{ currentValue }}</span>`,
  styleUrls: ['./timer.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class TimerComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() startAt = 0;

  @Output() counter = new EventEmitter<string>();

  currentValue = '';
  constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit(){
  }

  public start(){
    this.currentValue = this.formatValue(this.startAt);
    this.changeDetector .detectChanges();
  }

  private formatValue(v){
    const minutes = Math.floor(v/60);
    const formattedMinutes = (minutes > 9) ? minutes : ('0' + minutes);

    const seconds = v%60;
    const formattedSeconds = (seconds > 9) ? seconds : ('0' + seconds);

    return `${ formattedMinutes } : ${ formattedSeconds }`;
  }
}
```

**questions.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { TimerComponent } from '../timer/timer.component';

export class QuestionComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('counter', { read: TimerComponent })
  private counter: TimerComponent;

  ngOnInit() {
      this.counter.startAt = 2700;
      this.counter.start();
  }
}
```

**question.component.html**

```
<app-timer #counter></app-timer>
```

**ERROR**

```
core.js:6185 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'startAt' of undefined
    at QuestionComponent.ngOnInit (question.component.ts:122)
    at callHook (core.js:4686)
    at callHooks (core.js:4650)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:4591)
    at refreshView (core.js:11814)
    at refreshDynamicEmbeddedViews (core.js:13154)
    at refreshView (core.js:11819)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:13229)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11527)
    at refreshView (core.js:11848)
```

This is my code. Please help me out.

Comment: You're not creating an instance of `counter` in QuestionComponent.  Add a constructor.

Comment: And see this [Difference between Constructor and ngOnInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit)

Comment: @RamblinRose can you please tell how to create as I'm totally new in Angular

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between Constructor and ngOnInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit)

Comment: Without verifing it, please try to change the `ngOnInit` hook to `ngAfterViewInit`.

Comment: @mamichels The error is gone but the view is not rendered yet

Comment: you can also try adding `static: true` prop to the `@ViewChild` directive if there's no *ngIf in the template

Comment: @D Pro it solvee my problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the initialisation of the child with the `AfterViewInit` hook.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

export class QuestionComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.counter.startAt = 2700;
        this.counter.start();
    }

}
```