# Angular 9 : value is not updating while subscribe to emitter

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-event-emitter

I subscribed to emitter and I can see the output of this.productNumber in console. but it is not visible in the html file. I am using it like `{{productNumber}}`   in html file.

```
constructor(private http : HttpClientService) {
        this.http.orderDetailEmitter.subscribe((response)=>{
          this.productNumber=response;

        console.log("productNumber"+this.productNumber);
        });
       }
```

HTML file

```
<div>
          <div class="mat-display-1">you have {{productNumber}} product</div>
          <mat-form-field floatLabel="never" appearance="legacy" color="accent">


              <mat-label> Name</mat-label>

              <input matInput required>
              <mat-hint align="end">min 5 characters</mat-hint>

            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
```

[image]

please let me know if need more details

code for service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

export class Employee{
  constructor(
    public empId:string,
    public name:string,
    public designation:string,
    public salary:string,
    public isEditable : boolean
  ) {}
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpClientService {
  orderDetailEmitter = new EventEmitter<number>();


  constructor(
    private httpClient:HttpClient
  ) {

     }

     getEmployees()
  {

    return this.httpClient.get<Employee[]>('http://localhost:8081/fetchEmployees');
  }

  public deleteEmployee(employee) {
    return this.httpClient.delete<Employee>("http://localhost:8081/deleteEmployee" + "/"+ employee.emailid);
  }

  public createEmployee(employee) {
    return this.httpClient.post<Employee>("http://localhost:8081/employees", employee);
  }

  public updateEmployee(employee){
    return this.httpClient.post<Employee>("http://localhost:8081/updateEmployee", employee);
  }

  public createUser(user){
    return this.httpClient.post("http://localhost:8081/registration",user);
  }


}
```

Comment: It should work. Is there some css which is hiding it? Can you share the html file

Comment: added the html file

Comment: show your response so that we can get to know what it is proper or not

Comment: added the response.

Comment: The response doesn't look right. That doesn't look like a valid json. Does the API return response in string format?

Comment: yes, the response is a string. I am sending the data from one component to other via service using emitter

Comment: See [Difference between Constructor and ngOnInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your emitter emits before your template is ready. The `EventEmitter` is basically just a `Subject` and doesn't emit again if you subscribe. Thereby, the `EventEmitter` should technically only be used in an angular `Component` or `Directive` in combination with and `@Output`

In your code I do not see you emit anything in your `orderDetailEmitter`, but I guess this is something that needs to be replayed amongst subscribers. You should use a `ReplaySubject` for such a thing:

```
export class HttpClientService {
  readonly orderDetailEmitter = new ReplaySubject<number>(1);

  //...
}
```

The `1` as parameter indicates that a next subscriber should only receive the last emitted value of the stream.

Comment: I am using the default change detection strategy. but not sure how can i use the above code `this.productNumber = this.http.orderDetailEmitter;`. could you please help

Comment: I guess the `orderDetailEmitter` is an Observable. So if you assign it to productNumber, this will become that observable and you can pass it to the `async` pipe

Comment: I made it like this `productNumber;
  constructor(private http : HttpClientService) {
    this.productNumber=this.http.orderDetailEmitter;
   }`

Comment: we are not subscribing it, so do we will get the response ?

Comment: the `async` pipe takes care of that

Comment: Reading replaysubject for first time. Let me check it in detail. Is there any need to change other code ?

Comment: @sparsh610 no that's all. You can use the async pipe if you want. This way you don't have to unsubscribe when the component is destroyed. Otherwise you get memory leaks and double subscriptions when you revisit the component

Comment: now I am facing issue with code `this.http.orderDetailEmitter.emit(this.matBadgeNumber);`.as now I cannot emit it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211165/discussion-between-sparsh610-and-pierreduc).

Comment: @sparsh610 that's because a `ReplaySubject` is from rxjs which uses `next()` instead of `emit`. If you check the source code of angulars EventEmitter than the `emit()` is nothing more than a `next()` :)

Answer (score 1):

The constructor fires to early.  Move initialization code out of the constructor and into ngOnInit() for things your template depends on.

1. Implement OnInit in the component.
2. Create a function called ngOnInit() and put the subscribe code there.

Example:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  // keep the constructor for dependency injection only
  constructor(
    private httpClient:HttpClient
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
     this.http.orderDetailEmitter.subscribe((response)=>{
        this.productNumber=response;

        console.log("productNumber"+this.productNumber);
      });
  }

  ...
```

Comment: Try setting productNumber to a static value.  productNumber = 5.  Does that value show in the template?