# Angular .subscribe executes at the end after the ngOnInit

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

I am new to angular. I am trying the below code to populate a pie chart.
I am assigning the values inside the constructor. But here the method .subscribe executes at the end after the ngOnInit() executes.
And it displays undefined as the value of this.TestVar

```
cities: Observable<DataModel>;
TestVar: string;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

this.cities = this.http.get<DataModel>('./assets/data.json');

    this.cities.subscribe(events => {
      this.TestVar = events[0].District;
    });
}
```

```
ngOnInit() {
    let chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        theme: "light2",
        animationEnabled: true,
        exportEnabled: true,
        title:{
            text: "Monthly Expense"
        },
        data: [{
            type: "pie",
            showInLegend: true,
            toolTipContent: "<b>{name}</b>: ${y} (#percent%)",
            indexLabel: "{name} - #percent%",
            dataPoints: [
                { y: 450, name: this.TestVar },
                { y: 120, name: "Insurance" },
                { y: 300, name: "Traveling" },
                { y: 800, name: "Housing" },
                { y: 150, name: "Education" },
                { y: 150, name: "Shopping"},
                { y: 250, name: "Others" }
            ]
        }]
    });

    chart.render();
}
```

I tried adding the below code inside ngOnInit() even. But it didnt fix my issue.

```
this.cities.subscribe(events => {
      this.TestVar = events[0].District;
});
```

Appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: Don't you need to render the chart _after_ you've got the data back from the subscription?

Comment: Observables are `async` , which means you're trying to use the value of `this.TestVar` before your http request is finished and is therefore still `undefined`

Comment: Isuru, put all the code in ngOnInit INSIDE subscribe function, and move the this.cities.subscribe to ngOnInit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead, bringing the chart creation and rendering inside the async block of the observable:

```
cities: Observable<DataModel>;
TestVar: string;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.cities = this.http.get<DataModel>('./assets/data.json');

  this.cities.subscribe(events => {
    this.TestVar = events[0].District;

    let chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
      theme: "light2",
      animationEnabled: true,
      exportEnabled: true,
      title: {
        text: "Monthly Expense"
      },
      data: [{
        type: "pie",
        showInLegend: true,
        toolTipContent: "<b>{name}</b>: ${y} (#percent%)",
        indexLabel: "{name} - #percent%",
        dataPoints: [
          { y: 450, name: this.TestVar },
          { y: 120, name: "Insurance" },
          { y: 300, name: "Traveling" },
          { y: 800, name: "Housing" },
          { y: 150, name: "Education" },
          { y: 150, name: "Shopping" },
          { y: 250, name: "Others" }
        ]
      }]
    });

    chart.render();
  });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Observables` are `async` , which means you're trying to use the value of `this.TestVar` before your http request is finished and is therefore still undefined.

You can stay synchronous if you initialise the chart after the observable is finished:

```
 cities: Observable<DataModel>;
    TestVar: string;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.cities.subscribe(events => {
          this.TestVar = events[0].District;
          this.init();
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
       this.cities = this.http.get<DataModel>('./assets/data.json');
    }

public init(): void {
let chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
            theme: "light2",
            animationEnabled: true,
            exportEnabled: true,
            title:{
                text: "Monthly Expense"
            },
            data: [{
                type: "pie",
                showInLegend: true,
                toolTipContent: "<b>{name}</b>: ${y} (#percent%)",
                indexLabel: "{name} - #percent%",
                dataPoints: [
                    { y: 450, name: this.TestVar },
                    { y: 120, name: "Insurance" },
                    { y: 300, name: "Traveling" },
                    { y: 800, name: "Housing" },
                    { y: 150, name: "Education" },
                    { y: 150, name: "Shopping"},
                    { y: 250, name: "Others" }
                ]
            }]
        });

        chart.render();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

Call the code to create and render your `chart` *after* you've got the data back from your `http.get` call.

## Longer version

`TestVar` is undefined because you're trying to use the value before it's been populated by your `subscribe` callback function.

`Observable`s stream data asynchronously (not to be confused with `async`/`await` with promises). Have a read of the [RxJs Docs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable) to familiarize yourself with how they work and how to use them.

Your `http.get` call is returning the data back after you've already created and rendered the chart. At which time when you're creating/rendering, the `TestVar` value is still `undefined`, as it's not yet been set.

You need to set your `TestVar` value *inside* the callback, and *then* use the code you're using to set up and render your chart, like so:

```
TestVar: string;

constructor(private readonly _http: HttpClient) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this._http.get<DataModel>('./assets/data.json')
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.TestVar = data[0].District;

      // code to render chart AFTER you've retrieved the value
    });
}
```

Note that you don't need to create and assign `cities` class variable of `Observable<DataModel>`, as you're only using it locally and nowhere else, and can instead "chain" the call to returned `Observable` to subscribe to it.

Note that it's advisable to create and subscribe to things inside the `ngOnInit()`, rather than the constructor. `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook indicates that Angular has created the component and all the bindings are ready, so you're not creating all the things inside it before Angular can render anything. Here's [a much better explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit) on SO about the differences between a `constructor` and `ngOnInit`.

---

## Better still:

You're only using the `TestVar` value once/locally, so I don't see a need for setting it as a class variable (like with the `cities` class variable).

Instead, just grab the value and use it inside your callback:

```
// no need for the TestVar inside the class

constructor(private readonly _http: HttpClient) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this._http.get<DataModel>('./assets/data.json')
    .subscribe(data => {
      const district = data[0].District;

      // use the district variable when setting up your chart
    });
}
```

---

## Even better still:

Extract your chart creation code into its own private function inside your class, which takes the `District` value as an input, to keep your code nice and clean, rather than having a big long `ngOnInit()` function.

It will make your code a lot more readable and easier to see what's going on:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this._http.get<DataModel>('./assets/data.json')
    .subscribe(data => {
      const district = data[0].District;

      // then set up the chart
      this.initializeChart(district);
    });
}

private initializeChart(district: string) {
  // your code to initialize chart, using the district param passed in
}
```