# Angular inject component in innerHtml

Tags: angular

I'm setting HTML returned from the API in my Angular component:

```
<div [innerHTML]="content"></div>
```

content in this example is something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>[audioPlayer:file.mp3]</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now I would like to inject the actual  component inside the table cell.

If I make a certain container, I can create the component with createComponent:

```
audioPlayerComponentRef: ComponentRef<AudioPlayerComponent>;
@ViewChild('placeholder', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container;

const factory: ComponentFactory<AudioPlayerComponent> = 
this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(AudioPlayerComponent);
this.audioPlayerComponentRef = this.container.createComponent(factory);
```

Then I can inject it into a container in the template:

```
<div #placeholder></div>
```

However, going back to my original goal, I can't use such a container, as the component needs to be injected into a specific position into an innerHtml block.

I've been brainstorming all day, but I can't see any way to achieve this.

Comment: I’m afraid you have to rethink your approach. You cannot have a functional angular component inside innerHtml..

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, this is contrary to the way Angular works. `[innerHTML]` is not parsed for any Angular functionality. No component selectors or even a `ViewContainerRef` can be found there. Rather, even remotely suspicious HTML, CSS and JS is removed as a security measure as Angular only trusts its own templates.

So `InnerHTML` is a no-go. But I was in the same boat myself and have written a library to solve this exact problem. With it, you can freely load dynamic components into strings without compromising security. If you're still stuck on this, [you might wanna have a look at it](https://github.com/MTobisch/ngx-dynamic-hooks).