# ngOnInit vs constructor in Angular

Tags: angular

From here: https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/what-is-the-difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit-in-angular/#ngoninit-vs-constructor-in-angular

> *ngOnInit:* Invoked by Angular when component is initialized
>     *constructor:* Constructor is automatically called at the time of creating object of the class

How do we know when component is initialized? Which function is responsible for this?

> *ngOnInit:* Everything is ready at the time of invocation.
>      *constructor:* Not everything in component is initialized at the time of invocation

What is "everything" that is ready at the time of invocation?

https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit

> A callback method that is invoked immediately after the ***default change detector has checked the directive's data-bound properties for the first time***, ***and before any of the view or content children have been checked.*** It is invoked only once when the directive is instantiated.

Also, please explain the bold lines in the above quote.

Comment: Maybe this better explains it for you? [Hooking into the component lifecycle](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-event-sequence)

Comment: `How do we know when component is initialized? Which function is responsible for this?` ← When `ngOnInit` is called, that is why it exists and that is how "you know".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between Constructor and ngOnInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the exection order of various functions during the lifecycle of a component

- constructor
- OnChanges
- OnInit
- DoCheck
- AfterContentInit
- AfterContentChecked
- AfterViewInit
- AfterViewChecked
- OnDestroy

So by the time the constructor is called the change detection has not yet completed and some of the variables might not be initialized (for eg. input variables with `@Input()` decorator). However by the time `ngOnInit()` is hit, the component has been properly initialized.

Comment: Thank you. If we initialize the variables inside the constructor, then they will get initialized first. Why is that not preferred?

Comment: In theory, a variable might depend on another variable that might not yet be available or properly initialized in the constructor. If you were to initialize a variable with a constant, then it doesn't matter. It could also be done in the variable definition outside the constructor.