# Should I initialise an Angular service in its constructor or in the ngOnInit method of the app.component?

Tags: angular, service, constructor, initialization, ngoninit

I'm new to Angular.  I have a service that needs to subscribe to a subject provided by another service. If this was a component, I would create the subscription in the ngOnInit method of the component.  NgOnInit isn't called for Services, though.  I have created an initialise method to create the subscription but I'm not sure where best to call it from.  I have seen it done two ways:

1) Call the initialise method in the service constructor

2) Inject the service into the app.component and call the service initialise method in the app.component's ngOnInit method e.g.

method 1:

```
export class MyService{

    constructor(private myRequiredService: RequiredService) {
        this.initialiseSubs();
    }

    initaliseSubs(){
        //code to set up subscriptions
    }
}
```

---

Method 2

---

```
export class MyService{

    constructor(private myRequiredService: RequiredService) {}

    initaliseSubs(){
        //code to set up subscriptions
    }
}
```

---

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'my-app';

  constructor(private myService:MyService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.myService.initialiseSubs();

  }
}
```

Both methods seem to work but I would welcome advice as to which is preferable. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service is the place where you define your observables, e.g. `getAllEmployees()`. The components are the place where you use those services; e.g. by injecting them into the constructor).

```js
    export class MyService{
    
        constructor(private myRequiredService: RequiredService) {}
    
        getAllEmployees():Observable<Employee[]>{
           
           // return Observables of type Employee[]
        }
    }
```

Suppose now you have a component called `EmployeesList`, which is responsible for showing all the employees data. Firstly, you need to inject the service into the constructor. Next, you call the `getAllEmployees` service method and subscribe in order to to produce a result "aka data".

```js
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    
    export class EmployeesList implements OnInit{
      private employees: Employee[];
    
      constructor(private myService:MyService){}
    
      ngOnInit(): void{
         // it's better to do the subscription inside ngOnInit.
        this.myService.getAllEmployees().subscribe(
          employees => {
             this.employees = employees; 
          }
        );  
      }

    }
```

That's basically how you should do it. However, for better development and user experience, I advice using `angular resolvers`. Resolvers are basically methods that can be attached to a specific route and angular will call them before rendering the component.
But that's considered as an advanced topic, I will not post any codes for that unless you asked me for.

Please mark it as correct if the answer did help you.
All the best!

**Edit**
After discussing below in the comments, I understood that you have different back-ends to communicate with depending on the current route, I would handle this case just like this:

```js
    // inside the component 
    constructor(private router: Router) {}
    ngOnInit(){
            // You need to find 
            this.myService.getAllEmployees(this.router.url).subscribe(
              employees => {
                 this.employees = employees; 
              }
    
            );
      
    }

// inside the service file:

    export class MyService{
        
            constructor(private myRequiredService: RequiredService) {}
        
            getAllEmployees(URL: string):Observable<Employee[]>{
               // decide which back-end to connect with depending on the URL
               switch(url){
                case "example1":
                                URL = "url1";
                         break;
                case "example2":
                                URL = "url2";
                         break;
               }
               // Connect to the resource using URL param
               // return Observables of type Employee[]
            }
    }
```

Comment: "it's better to do the subscription inside ngOnInit."
- Can you elaborate on why that is the "better" way?

Comment: Many thanks for a speedy answer. Your example is how 90% of my app works.  I just have an unusual case. The app talks to different backends depending on the route used to access it (sites have their own urls and own backends). A sites service sets the site based on the url.  An auth service passes a login request to the relevant backend,  If the site changes, the front end should require the user to log in again. As such, the auth service needs to subscribe to a site subject in the sites service. Hence the need to initialise a subscription in a service to a subject in another service.

Comment: @GeorgeKitching You welcome, I understood that the back-end url of the service method is always changing, I think you should pass the URL as a parameter to the service instead of subscribing inside the service.
because you can know which route is called from inside the component, depending on that you can decide which back-end to call.

Comment: @PhilippMeissner please take a look at this answer here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35763811/10121188

Comment: @FurqanS.Mahmoud. Thank you. That might work. I'll give it some thought.  Is there any reason for avoiding subscribing within a service? It seems to work, but I am keen to avoid unforseen pitfalls.

Comment: @GeorgeKitching it will work, but the code will not be consistent, I will edit the answer to give you a close look.

Comment: @FurqanS.Mahmoud. Yes, I think you've convinced me. I might have been overthinking it.  Doing it the way you suggest actually simplifies something else I need to do too.  Thanks again for your help.