# How to show very deeply nested components when angular changeDetector does'nt detect them?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component named Grid, its template is:

```
<div *ngFor="let row of item.rows">
  <div *ngFor="let col of row.cols">
    <div *ngFor="let grid of col.items">
      <app-grid [item]="grid"></app-grid>
      <!-- another content -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and a parent component with the content:

```
<div *ngFor="let entireGrid of ser.Grids">
    <app-grid [item]="ser.entireGrid"></app-grid>
</div>
```

In my parent component ts I have this constructor:

```
constructor(public ser:myService){
ser.getGrids().subscribe(data=>{
data.grids.foreach(g=>{
ser.grids.push(g);
});
});
```

and myService has the variable:

```
grids:Array<Grid>=[];
```

my problem is - each entireGrid is nested very deeply (inside it there are many rows and inside them many cols and inside them many grids and inside them many rows again...)
so when I reshow the parent component the deepest grids don't appear, only when I click on one of the grids that does appear they appear.
I've tried to put `cd.detectChanges` in the grid component in the functions `ngOnInit` , `ngAfterViewChecked` , `ngDoCheck` but nothing worked.
does somone have an idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Provide entireGrid via Observable and async pipe that would refresh it inpure:

   this.entireGrid = of(entireGrid);

   <app-grid [item]="entireGrid | async">
2. In place you define entireGrid create new reference:

   this.entireGrid = { ...entireGrid };

Comment: Where to put this.entireGrid = of(entireGrid);?

Comment: In your component.ts which is container of <app-grid ..

Try the option number 2 which is easier first :)

Comment: What is this 'of'? I tried to put this line in the constructor of the component and I got the error: Cannot find name 'of'.

Comment: it is RXJS operator [of](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of). But if you are not familliar with it better try creating new object reference.

Comment: I didn't understane the second option. can you explain a little more?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add there parent.component.ts, so I could update how code should look there :)?

Comment: I have now updated it.
Note that now the parent.component.html is a bit more complex...

Comment: Read this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit](Why you should use ngOnInit instead of constructor in such situations ...) and I would answer question in new topic

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if it would work because still it is a part from your code but try this...

> if this would not work, edit your question and put there code from **myService**

> parent.component.ts:

```
grids: Observable<Grid[]> = this.ser.getGrids().pipe(
    map({grids} => grids)
);

constructor(public ser:myService) {
}
```

> parent component content:

```
<div *ngFor="let entireGrid of grids | async">
     <app-grid [item]="entireGrid"></app-grid>
</div>
```