# Where to initialise a FormGroup in Reactive forms?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular11

Using Angular 11 with Typescript 4 in Strict Mode I have:

```
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit { 

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({ 
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(40)]],
    });

  }
```

I get the build error:

```
 Property 'form' has no initialiser and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
```

Shouldn't the FormGroup be initialised on ngOnInit?

Comment: In strict mode, constructor is where we use to set initially our property. we move our rest of initialization logic in ngoninit.

Comment: My preference is usually to initialize the form when declaring the property `form: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({ ...  });`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Shouldn't the FormGroup be initialised on ngOnInit?

It doesn't have to be; I find it simplest to initialize most things directly on the class like this:

```
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit { 

  form = this.formBuilder.group({ 
    email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    name:  ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(40)]],
  });

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

}
```

This works fine with [`strictPropertyInitialization`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#--strictpropertyinitialization).

The exception is when initializing something that requires data from the DOM (*`@Input`, `@ViewChild`, etc*)  Since those things get initialized in the various [Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-event-sequence) as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48499980/1858357):

- `@Input()`           →  `ngOnInit`
- `@ViewChild()`       →  `ngAfterViewInit`
- `@ContentChildren()` →  `ngAfterContentInit`

Initializing something that depends on say, an `@Input()`, would be done in the corresponding lifecycle hook, `ngOnInit`, however, this does not appease the strict rule, so the [`Definite Assignment Assertion Operator`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions) `!` is needed.

```
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit { 
  @Input() input!: number;

  inputDoubled!: number;
  
  form = this.formBuilder.group({ 
    email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    name:  ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(40)]],
  });

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.inputDoubled = this.input * 2;
  }
}
```