# Initializing object when strictNullChecks used in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, null, undefined

I have an interface called `IUser` and uses `strictNullChecks` in the typescript setting. I want to use a variable of `IUser` in the class like below:

```
class UserAccount {
    user: IUser;
}
```

The above code will generate the error:

`Property 'user' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.`

I can fix this with:

```
class UserAccount {
    user: IUser;
    constructor() {
        user = new User();
    }
}
```

But from a run time perspective, the `user` can be set only after a while after the display is complete. There is a latency for getting the data for the `user` from the server. The setting of the `user` is done through an `RxJS` observable which works only reactively.

What type of initialization I can do for `user` so that it can be set only later time. Setting `user` to `null` or `undefined` may not be correct because I use `strictNullChecks` and showing the intention that the object will be present from the beginning. But a valid object for `user` can't exist until the server call is complete.

*** UPDATE ****

This is a little more better example than the above:

```
export class AddPersonDialogComponent {

  selectedPerson1: IPersonForTypeahead;
  selectedPerson2: IPersonForTypeahead;
  selectedPerson3: IPersonForTypeahead;

  ...
}
```

The 3 `selectedPerson` objects are assigned values when the user select them from three 3 dropdowns in the dialog. These three properties start with nothing but if the user select people from a drop down in the dialog, they are set.

Comment: "*showing the intention that the object will be present from the beginning*" and "*the `user` can be set only after a while*"  don't go together. Which one is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make your usage of `UserAccount` to be an observable, like this:

```js
userAccount$: Observable<UserAccount> = this.service.getUser().pipe(
    map(user => new UserAccount(user))
);
```

The idea here is to not construct your `UserAccount` until you have all the data needed to do so.  This goes along with your idea "*But a valid object for user can't exist until the server call is complete*" .

Comment: I used `UserAccount` as an example. This class can be an angular component class. So, the parent class can't be converted to an `Observable`. The question is around the property `user` and what it can be initialized with when `strictNullChecks` is used.

Comment: Can you add an example to your question?  Maybe [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66603888/where-to-initialise-a-formgroup-in-reactive-forms) may be of some help for you.

Comment: I added an example under **UPDATE** in the original post.