# Initializing properties directly VS in ngOninit method

Tags: angular

What is the difference between initialzing a component's property directly in the component class VS initializing it in the ngOninit method ?

**Example :**

```
@Component({})
export class AppComponent {
    property: string = 'some initial value'
}

   **VS**

@Component({})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    property: string;

    ngOninit(): void {
        this.property = 'some initial value';
    }
}
```

Comment: You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66603888/where-to-initialise-a-formgroup-in-reactive-forms/66607035#66607035) helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read about [Angular Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

Here you had a simple example where you are just setting the `property` a static value but for a case where `property`'s value depends on an API service then you should use `life-cycle hooks` for playing with the values

A simple example of setting the `property` with a value which you get from a API `service` which will get data from a `REST API`

```
@Component({})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    property: string;
    constructor(private apiService:ApiService){}
    ngOninit(): void {
        this.apiService.getAPIData.subscribe((data)=>{
          this.property = data;
        });
    }
}
```

[Here](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-constructor-ngoninit-lifecycle-hook) is another comparison which explains `@Input` availability from `ngOninit`

Answer (score 2):

If anything is statically initialized, there is basically no difference. If your parameters depend on `@Input` parameters on the other hand, these will not be available in the constructor, but will be set before the `ngOnInit` hook is called. So the common pattern is to treat the `ngOnInit` method as a constructor block.