# Angular - TypeError: Cannot read property 'clearValidators' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to dynamically remove validation from my Angular Reactive Form.

The error:

[image]

My code initializing the form:

```js
experienceForm = this.fb.group({
  'positionTitle': ['', Validators.required],
  'companyName': ['', Validators.required],
  'startDate': ['', Validators.required],
  'endDate': ['', Validators.required]
});
```

The function responsible for dynamically removing the validation:

```js
togglePresent(event: any) {
   if (event.checked) {
      this.present = true;
      this.experienceForm.get('endDate')?.clearValidators();
      this.experienceForm.get('endDate')?.updateValueAndValidity();
   }
   else { this.present = false; }
 }
```

Essentially, the function runs anytime a checkbox is marked. My frustration with this stems from the fact that I'm implementing code from the Angular documentation.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where do you initialize the form in [constructor or in ngOnInit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35763811/7149235)? Where do you call the togglePresent method?

Comment: I do not initialize the form in either. I call the togglePresent method in my HTML template whenever a checkbox value is toggled.

Comment: @DaveGuerrero so you call togglePresent from `<input type="check" (change)="togglePresent($event)" />` ? Right ?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda exactly.

Comment: Try `this.experienceForm.controls.endData.clearValidators()` this

Comment: Sorry for not including the HTML, I didn't consider it very relevant.

Comment: @iamentafaz I implemented your solution and received the same error.

Comment: @DaveGuerrero https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5sjkxm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts check this example here its working.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda I receive this error when I implement it in my project: Property 'experienceForm' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor. I believe this is a result of one of the latest Angular updates.

Comment: @DaveGuerrero show your code on stackblitz.

Comment: @DaveGuerrero in which line you have declared this variable `experienceForm: FormGroup;` inside your project ?

Comment: @DaveGuerrero, the error in console is pointing to addExperience function/line at line no:78. If possible can u add that code also in your question..

Comment: It is working fine in [my example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e9fl6s?file=src/app/app.component.ts). You need to use `this.experienceForm.controls.endDate.updateValueAndValidity();` as well after what I suggested earlier.

Comment: It won't compile correctly, but you can see the markup: https://angular-ivy-zh2zvi.stackblitz.io

Comment: @DaveGuerrero share full link of stackblitz. share link of your code editor stackblitz not preview link

Comment: @GaurangDhorda https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tukka7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @DaveGuerrero change exprerienceForm initialization inside ngOnInit()

Comment: You have not create variable for `experienceForm` and you have to call `this.experianceForm` when initialize in ngOnInit()

Comment: As said eralier @DaveGuerrero, the ```this.experienceForm.controls.controlName.clearValidators();``` in ```addExperience()``` is giving you an error. Which control do you want to reset as ```control.controlName``` is not valid so it will return undefined.. hence the error?

Comment: I actually found and resolved the issue -- it was on line 83 in the stackblitz code. I was calling the clearValidator method where it shouldn't have been. I simply deleted that line and it worked.

Comment: @DaveGuerrero https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5sjkxm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fedit-experience-modal%2Fedit-experience-modal.component.ts here is demo working

Comment: @DaveGuerrero again, your initialization of experianceForm is not right. First define global instance variable and then call it wtih this.experianceForm

Comment: @GaurangDhorda With the latest version of Angular it throws me an error when I do that because I'm not initializing it to anything. I used to do it the way you're suggesting.

Comment: @DaveGuerrero you can assign it temporally like this `experienceForm: FormGroup = <FormGroup>{};` and then you can create you FormGroup with this.fb.formGroup({}) inside ngOnInit().

Answer (score 0):

Arent you missing the 'this' in experienceForm = this.fb....?

So it would be this.experienceForm = .........

So it accessable from other methods in that component