# Angular - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach') by trying to manipulate variable after an HTTP call

Tags: angular, typescript, http, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to manipulate a variable after an HTTP call.
I want to use functions such as `.push()` or `.forEach()`, but it doesn't allow me because data isn't assigned to the variable at first.

I get an error in the console:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')

My Component:

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {TablesService} from "../tables.service";

@Component({...})

export class BigQueryComponent implements OnInit {
  fetchedData: any;
  DATA: any;

  constructor(private tableService: TablesService) {
    this.tableService.fetchAPI().subscribe((data) => {
      this.fetchedData = data;
    })
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getQueryData();
  }

  getQueryData() {
    this.fetchedData.forEach( dataset => { 
      this.DATA.push( dataset );
    });
  }

}
```

My Service:

```js
export class TablesService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  fetchAPI() {
    return this.http.get('https://.../products');
  }
}
```

How could I do this? I've tried to add Observable to the HTTP function, but I'm not sure how should it be done correctly.

Comment: And what is the value of `fetchedData` _before_ the call completes? Either you need a sensible default value, or you should use observables with e.g. the async pipe to handle the data.

Comment: data is undefined at first. I want to fetch data from API and after it's fetched I want to manipulate it. Not sure how observables with async pipe works, but ill take a look into that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirement in the comment, you should move the logic from `getQueryData` to the `subscribe` function of `fetchAPI`. Thus, when the observable is returned, the `fetchData` will be assigned with `data` and proceed with the following logic.

And remove `this.tableService.fetchAPI().subscribe` code from `constructor`.

Normally we use `ngOnInit()` for initialization work as discussed in this question: [Difference between Constructor and ngOnInit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35763811/8017690).

```js
constructor(private tableService: TablesService) { }

getQueryData() {
  this.tableService.fetchAPI().subscribe((data) => {
    this.fetchedData = data;

    this.fetchedData.forEach( dataset => { 
      this.DATA.push( dataset );
    });  
  });
}
```

**Note:**

Will suggest these two variables are defined with `array` type.

```js
fetchedData: any[];
DATA: any[];
```