# How to use property binding in custom directive?

Tags: angular

**Directive**:

```
// highlight.directive.ts 
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHighlight]',
})
export class HighlightDirective {
  @Input() yourColor: any = 'red';
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = this.yourColor;
  }
}
```

**Consumer**:

```
// app.component.html
<div appHighlight [yourColor]="'blue'">Testing</div>
```

**Result**:

[image]

### Question

Why can't I pass `blue` to `yourColor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move your code from `constructor` to `ngOnInit`. Use `constructor` in Angular only for injecting dependencies, but `ngOnInit` for executing a code when component is mounted.

Here is more info about that: [Difference between Constructor and ngOnInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using two-way binding:

```
 // highlight.directive.ts
 export class HighlightDirective {
        yourColor: any = 'red';

        ngOnInit() {
       // change color in method
         this.yourColor = ‘blue’;
         }
       
       }

  // app.component.html
  <div appHighlight style=“background-color=    {{yourColor}}”>Testing</div>
```

Comment: it is not property binding.